# Create ArrayList from array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion

```java
Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3)};
```

How do I convert the above variable of type `Element[]` into a variable of type [`ArrayList<Element>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)?

```java
ArrayList<Element> arrayList = ...;
```

Answer (score 5122, accepted):

You can use the following instruction:

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: Yep. And in the (most common) case where you just want a list, the `new ArrayList` call is unecessary as well.

Comment: @Luron - just use `List<ClassName> list = Arrays.asList(array)`

Comment: @Calum and @Pool - as noted below in Alex Miller's answer, using `Arrays.asList(array)` without passing it into a new `ArrayList` object will fix the size of the list. One of the more common reasons to use an `ArrayList` is to be able to dynamically change its size, and your suggestion would prevent this.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the new ArrayList<Element>(...) part is necessary if you want to perform mutative (like remove) operations with an iterator.

Comment: Arrays.asList() is a horrible function, and you should never just use its return value as is. It breaks the List template, so always use it in the form indicated here, even if it does seem redundant. Good answer.

Comment: A caveat: I just run into a misbehavior of Java 6: when Element is a primitive (e.g. the array is int[]), asList creates List<int[]> .

Comment: @Adam `Arrays.asList()` is a very useful method when you want a list backed by a specific array. For example `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(myarray))` shuffles the *original* array.

Comment: @lbalazscs true, but I would say that's pretty close to a hack (even if the shuffle method was intended to be used that way), because you're basically tricking it into thinking it's dealing with a List when it's not. Handy, but I still say it's a horrible function. My argument is basically that the asList() method is misleading because it looks like it returns a List representation of the given array, when in fact it returns an only-partially-implemented List representation.

Comment: @Adam Please study the javadoc for java.util.List. The contract for add allows them to throw an UnsupportedOperationException. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29  Admittedly, from an object-oriented perspective it is not very nice that many times you have to know the concrete implementation in order to use a collection - this was a pragmatic design choice in order to keep the framework simple.

Comment: If I have Array `a`, and convert it to ArrayList `b` using above method as `b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));`, I cannot retrieve an element from `b` using `b[3]`, becuase `b` contains a list?

Answer (score 1006):

Given:

```
Element[] array = new Element[] { new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3) };
```

The simplest answer is to do:

```
List<Element> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

This will work fine.  But some caveats:

1. The list returned from asList has **fixed size**.  So, if you want to be able to add or remove elements from the returned list in your code, you'll need to wrap it in a new `ArrayList`.  Otherwise you'll get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.
2. The list returned from `asList()` is backed by the original array.  If you modify the original array, the list will be modified as well.  This may be surprising.

Comment: Arrays.asList() merely creates an ArrayList by wrapping the existing array so it is O(1).

Comment: Wrapping in a new ArrayList() will cause all elements of the fixed size list to be iterated and added to the new ArrayList so is O(n).

Comment: To clarify, `Arrays.asList()` creates a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` (static nested class in `java.util.Arrays`), not a `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 404):

*<sup>(old thread, but just 2 cents as none mention Guava or other libs and some other details)</sup>*

## If You Can, Use Guava

It's worth pointing out the Guava way, which greatly simplifies these shenanigans:

### Usage

#### For an Immutable List

Use the [`ImmutableList`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java) class and its [`of()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#L108) and [`copyOf()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#L235) factory methods <sup>(elements can't be null)</sup>:

```
List<String> il = ImmutableList.of("string", "elements");  // from varargs
List<String> il = ImmutableList.copyOf(aStringArray);      // from array
```

#### For A Mutable List

Use the [`Lists`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java) class and its [`newArrayList()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java#L84) factory methods:

```
List<String> l1 = Lists.newArrayList(anotherListOrCollection);    // from collection
List<String> l2 = Lists.newArrayList(aStringArray);               // from array
List<String> l3 = Lists.newArrayList("or", "string", "elements"); // from varargs
```

Please also note the similar methods for other data structures in other classes, for instance in [`Sets`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java).

### [Why Guava?](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki)

The main attraction could be to reduce the clutter due to generics for type-safety, as the use of the Guava [factory methods](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#static-constructors) allow the types to be inferred most of the time. However, this argument holds less water since Java 7 arrived with the new diamond operator.

But it's not the only reason (and Java 7 isn't everywhere yet): the shorthand syntax is also very handy, and the methods initializers, as seen above, allow to write more expressive code. You do in one Guava call what takes 2 with the current Java Collections.

---

## If You Can't...

### For an Immutable List

Use the JDK's [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) class and its [`asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) factory method, wrapped with a [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)):

```
List<String> l1 = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(anArrayOfElements));
List<String> l2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("element1", "element2"));
```

Note that the returned type for `asList()` is a `List` using a concrete `ArrayList` implementation, but **it is NOT** `java.util.ArrayList`. It's an inner type, which emulates an `ArrayList` but actually directly references the passed array and makes it "write through" (modifications are reflected in the array).

It forbids modifications through some of the `List` API's methods by way of simply extending an `AbstractList` (so, adding or removing elements is unsupported), however it allows calls to `set()` to override elements. Thus this list isn't truly immutable and a call to `asList()` should be wrapped with `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

See the next step if you need a mutable list.

### For a Mutable List

Same as above, but wrapped with an actual `java.util.ArrayList`:

```
List<String> l1  = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));    // Java 1.5 to 1.6
List<String> l1b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));          // Java 1.7+
List<String> l2  = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b")); // Java 1.5 to 1.6
List<String> l2b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));       // Java 1.7+
```

---

## For Educational Purposes: The Good ol' Manual Way

```
// for Java 1.5+
static <T> List<T> arrayToList(final T[] array) {
  final List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>(array.length);

  for (final T s : array) {
    l.add(s);
  }
  return (l);
}

// for Java < 1.5 (no generics, no compile-time type-safety, boo!)
static List arrayToList(final Object[] array) {
  final List l = new ArrayList(array.length);

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    l.add(array[i]);
  }
  return (l);
}
```

Comment: +1 But note that the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is mutable in that you can still `set` elements - it just isn't resizable. For immutable lists without Guava you might mention [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList\(java.util.List\)).

Answer (score 255):

Since this question is pretty old, it surprises me that nobody suggested the simplest form yet:

```
List<Element> arraylist = Arrays.asList(new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3));
```

As of Java 5, `Arrays.asList()` takes a varargs parameter and you don't have to construct the array explicitly.

Comment: In particular, `List<String> a = Arrays.asList("first","second","third")`

Comment: I think, the reason is 1) the requester wanted an ArrayList and 2) the result list cannot grow. So, you cannot add elements afterwards.

Answer (score 228):

```
new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Make sure that `myArray` is the same type as `T`. You'll get a compiler error if you try to create a `List<Integer>` from an array of `int`, for example.

Answer (score 114):

Another way (although essentially equivalent to the `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array))` solution performance-wise:

```
Collections.addAll(arraylist, array);
```

Comment: Until Java 16 the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,T...)) stated: _The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run **significantly faster** under most implementations._

Comment: See [this question](/q/3343766 "Why is Collections.addAll supposed to be faster than c.addAll?") for comparision discussion

Answer (score 114):

## Java 9

In [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), you can use [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-E-E-) static factory method in order to create a `List` literal. Something like the following:

```
List<Element> elements = List.of(new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3));
```

This would return an [***immutable***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) list containing three elements. If you want a ***mutable*** list, pass that list to the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
new ArrayList<>(List.of(// elements vararg))
```

---

#### JEP 269: Convenience Factory Methods for Collections

[JEP 269](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269) provides some convenience factory methods for [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) API. These immutable static factory methods are built into the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interfaces in Java 9 and later.

Comment: List.of() will not return an instance of java.util.ArrayList, as requested in the original question. Therefore only the second option is a valid answer.

Answer (score 94):

You probably just need a List, not an ArrayList.  In that case you can just do:

```
List<Element> arraylist = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Comment: That will be backed by the original input array, which is why you (probably) want to wrap it in a new ArrayList.

Comment: Be careful with this solution. If you look, Arrays ISN'T returning a true java.util.ArrayList. It's returning an inner class that implements the required methods, but you cannot change the memebers in the list. It's merely a wrapper around an array.

Comment: You can cast the List<Element> item to an ArrayList<Element>

Comment: @Mikezx6r: little **correction**: it's a fixed-size list. You can change the elements of the list (`set` method), you cannot change the size of the list (not `add` or `remove` elements)!

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that it depends on what you want to do with the list. It's worth notng that if the OP simply wants to iterate through the elements, the array doesn't have to be converted at all.

Comment: @monksy No, you can't. As was said, it is a different kind of `ArrayList`.

Comment: This does not work if array element is of primitive type in Java 8. For details, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2607289/431698

Answer (score 78):

Another update, almost ending year 2014, you can do it with Java 8 too:

```
ArrayList<Element> arrayList = Stream.of(myArray).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

A few characters would be saved, if this could be just a `List`

```
List<Element> list = Stream.of(myArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It's probably best not to be implementation-dependent, but `Collectors.toList()` actually returns an `ArrayList`.

Comment: incorrect use of Stream.of(...); that will create a one element stream. Use Arrays.stream instead

Comment: I don't think so, the 2 options are valid but the Arrays.stream is slightly 'better' since you can create it with fixed size, using the overload method with 'start', 'end' args. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27888447/2619091

Answer (score 49):

If you use :

```
new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

you **may** create **and fill** two lists ! Filling twice a big list is exactly what you don't want to do because it will create another `Object[]` array each time the capacity needs to be extended.

Fortunately the JDK implementation is fast and `Arrays.asList(a[])` is very well done. It create a kind of ArrayList named Arrays.ArrayList where the Object[] data points directly to the array.

```
// in Arrays
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
//still in Arrays, creating a private unseen class
private static class ArrayList<E>

    private final E[] a;    
    ArrayList(E[] array) {
        a = array; // you point to the previous array
    }
    ....
}
```

The dangerous side is that **if you change the initial array, you change the List !** Are you sure you want that ? Maybe yes, maybe not.

If not, the most understandable way is to do this :

```
ArrayList<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>(myArray.length); // you know the initial capacity
for (Element element : myArray) {
    list.add(element);
}
```

Or as said @glglgl, you can create another independant ArrayList with :

```
new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

I love to use `Collections`, `Arrays`, or Guava. But if it don't fit, or you don't feel it, just write another inelegant line instead.

Comment: I fail to see the fundamental difference between your loop at the end of the answer and the `new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(myArray));` part which you discourage to use. Both do quite the same and have the same complexity.

Comment: The Collections one create a pointer at the beginning of the array. My loop create many pointers : one for each array member. So if the original array changes, my poiners are still directed toward the former values.

Comment: `new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(myArray));` does the same, it copies the `asList` to an `ArrayList`...

Answer (score 42):

In `Java 9` you can use:

```
List<String> list = List.of("Hello", "World", "from", "Java");
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: Note that this is not an ArrayList, as it was explicitely asked.

Answer (score 37):

According with the question the answer using java 1.7 is:

```
ArrayList<Element> arraylist = new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.<Element>asList(array));
```

However it's better always use the interface:

```
List<Element> arraylist = Arrays.<Element>asList(array);
```

Answer (score 34):

```
// Guava
import com.google.common.collect.ListsLists
...
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(aStringArray);
```

Answer (score 28):

Since Java 8 there is an easier way to transform:

```
import java.util.List;    
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public static <T> List<T> fromArray(T[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is easier than:

new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));

It's also unclear that it is more efficient in any way..

Answer (score 27):

You can convert using different methods

1. `List<Element> list = Arrays.asList(array);`
2. `List<Element> list = new ArrayList();

   Collections.addAll(list, array);`
3. `Arraylist list = new Arraylist();

   list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));`

For more detail you can refer to http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/converting-array-to-arraylist-in-java.html

Answer (score 26):

as all said this will do so

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4"));
```

and the common newest way to create array is **observableArrays**

**ObservableList:** A list that allows listeners to track changes when they occur.

for Java SE you can try

```
FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3));
```

that is according to [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html)

> observableArrayList()
> Creates a new empty observable list that is backed by an arraylist.
> observableArrayList(E... items)
> Creates a new observable array list with items added to it.

### **Update Java 9**

also in Java 9 it's a little bit easy:

```
List<String> list = List.of("element 1", "element 2", "element 3");
```

Answer (score 24):

You also can do it with stream in Java 8.

```
List<Element> elements = Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: As of **java 8**, `Collectors.toList()` will return an `ArrayList`. However this may differ in future versions on java.If you want a specific type of collection then use `Collectors.toCollection()` instead where you can specify which exact type of collection you would want to create.

Answer (score 18):

1. If we see the definition of `Arrays.asList()` method you will get something like this:

   ```
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) //varargs are of T type.
   ```

   So, you might initialize `arraylist` like this:

   ```
    List<Element> arraylist = Arrays.asList(new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3));
   ```

   > **Note** : each `new Element(int args)` will be treated as Individual Object and can be passed as a `var-args`.
2. There might be another answer for this question too.
   If you see declaration for `java.util.Collections.addAll()` method you will get something like this:

   ```
   public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... a);
   ```

   So, this code is also useful to do so

   ```
   Collections.addAll(arraylist, array);
   ```

Answer (score 14):

If the array is of a primitive type, the given answers won't work. But since Java 8 you can use:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work with `char` array, either.

Answer (score 12):

Another simple way is to add all elements from the array to a new ArrayList using a for-each loop.

```
ArrayList<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(Element e : array)
    list.add(e);
```

Answer (score 10):

We can easily convert an array to `ArrayList`.
We use Collection interface's `addAll()` method for the purpose of copying content from one list to another.

```
Arraylist arr = new Arraylist();
arr.addAll(Arrays.asList(asset));
```

Comment: This is less efficient than the accepted 9 year old answer.

Comment: One of `ArrayList`s constructors accepts a `? extends Collection<T>` argument, making the call to `addAll` redundant.

Answer (score 9):

Even though there are many perfectly written answers to this question, I will add my inputs.

Say you have `Element[] array = { new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3) };`

New ArrayList can be created in the following ways

```
ArrayList<Element> arraylist_1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
ArrayList<Element> arraylist_2 = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(new Element[] { new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3) }));

// Add through a collection
ArrayList<Element> arraylist_3 = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(arraylist_3, array);
```

And they very well support all operations of ArrayList

```
arraylist_1.add(new Element(4)); // or remove(): Success
arraylist_2.add(new Element(4)); // or remove(): Success
arraylist_3.add(new Element(4)); // or remove(): Success
```

But the following operations returns just a List view of an ArrayList and not actual ArrayList.

```
// Returns a List view of array and not actual ArrayList
List<Element> listView_1 = (List<Element>) Arrays.asList(array);
List<Element> listView_2 = Arrays.asList(array);
List<Element> listView_3 = Arrays.asList(new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3));
```

Therefore, they will give error when trying to make some ArrayList operations

```
listView_1.add(new Element(4)); // Error
listView_2.add(new Element(4)); // Error
listView_3.add(new Element(4)); // Error
```

More on List representation of array [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187083/benefits-of-creating-a-list-using-arrays-aslist).

Answer (score 9):

Simplest way to do so is by adding following code. Tried and Tested.

```
String[] Array1={"one","two","three"};
ArrayList<String> s1= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Array1));
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it in java 8 as follows

```
ArrayList<Element> list = (ArrayList<Element>)Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Downvoted because that cast looks very dangerous. nothing specifies that the type of list that is returned is actually an ArrayList, as the javadoc states: "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned"

Comment: If you want to explicitely create an ArrayList, try this: `ArrayList<String> list = Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Answer (score 9):

> Another Java8 solution *(I may have missed the answer among the large set. If so, my apologies).* This creates an ArrayList (as opposed to a List) i.e. one can delete elements

```
package package org.something.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Junk {

    static <T> ArrayList<T>  arrToArrayList(T[] arr){
        return Arrays.asList(arr)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] sArr = new String[]{"Hello", "cruel", "world"};
        List<String> ret = arrToArrayList(sArr);
        // Verify one can remove an item and print list to verify so
        ret.remove(1);
        ret.stream()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output is... 
Hello 
world

Answer (score 9):

Use the following code to convert an element array into an ArrayList.

```
Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3)};

ArrayList<Element>elementArray=new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    elementArray.add(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Given Object Array:**

```
Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3) , new Element(2)};
```

**Convert Array to List:**

```
List<Element> list = Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Convert Array to ArrayList**

```
ArrayList<Element> arrayList = Arrays.stream(array)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

**Convert Array to LinkedList**

```
LinkedList<Element> linkedList = Arrays.stream(array)
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

**Print List:**

```
list.forEach(element -> {
    System.out.println(element.i);
});
```

**OUTPUT**

1

2

3

Answer (score 6):

Already everyone has provided enough good answer for your problem. 
Now from the all suggestions, you need to decided which will fit your requirement. There are two types of collection which you need to know. One is unmodified collection and other one collection which will allow you to modify the object later.

So, Here I will give short example for two use cases.

- Immutable collection creation :: When you don't want to modify the collection object after creation

  `List<Element> elementList = Arrays.asList(array)`
- Mutable collection creation :: When you may want to modify the created collection object after creation.

  `List<Element> elementList = new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array));`

Comment: List<Element> elementList = Arrays.asList(array) creates a wrapper over the original array which makes original array available as List. Hence a wrapper object is created, nothing gets copied from the original array. Therefore, operations like add or remove elements are not allowed.

Comment: Note that your "immutable collection" is not really immutable - the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is just a wrapper over the original array, and allows individual items to be accessed and modified via `get` and `set`. You should probably clarify that you mean "not add or remove elements" instead of "immutable", which means to not change at all.

Answer (score 6):

Java 8’s Arrays class provides a stream() method which has overloaded versions accepting both primitive arrays and Object arrays.

```
/**** Converting a Primitive 'int' Array to List ****/

int intArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

List<Integer> integerList1 = Arrays.stream(intArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

/**** 'IntStream.of' or 'Arrays.stream' Gives The Same Output ****/

List<Integer> integerList2 = IntStream.of(intArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

/**** Converting an 'Integer' Array to List ****/

Integer integerArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

List<Integer> integerList3 = Arrays.stream(integerArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use **polymorphism** to declare the **ArrayList** while calling the **Arrays**-interface as following:

`List<Element> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));`

**Example:**

```
Integer[] array = {1};    // autoboxing
List<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

This should work like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Hi you can use this **`line of code`** , and it's the **simplest way**

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

or in case you use  **`Java 9`** you can also use this method:

```
List<String> list = List.of("Hello", "Java"); 
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 5):

For normal size arrays, above answers hold good. In case you have huge size of array and using java 8, you can do it using stream.

```
Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3)};
List<Element> list = Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Below code seems nice way of doing this.

```
new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Answer (score 3):

In java there are mainly 3 methods to convert an **array** to an **arrayList**

1. Using Arrays.asList() method : Pass the required array to this method and get a List object and pass it as a parameter to the constructor of the ArrayList class.

   ```
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);                   
   System.out.println(list);
   ```
2. Collections.addAll() method - Create a new list before using this method and then add array elements using this method to existing list.

   ```
   List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   Collections.addAll(list1, array);
   System.out.println(list1);
   ```
3. Iteration method - Create a new list. Iterate the array and add each element to the list.

   ```
   List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(String text:array) {
       list2.add(text);
   }
   System.out.println(list2);
   ```

you can refer [this document](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Conversion-of-Array-To-ArrayList-in-Java) too

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following 3 ways to create ArrayList from Array.

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};

//Method 1
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);          

//Method 2
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(list1, array);

//Method 3
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String text:array) {
   list2.add(text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is one more way that you can use to convert the array into an ArrayList. You can iterate over the array and insert each index into the ArrayList and return it back as in ArrayList.

This is shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {new String("David"), new String("John"), new String("Mike")};

        ArrayList<String> theArrayList = convertToArrayList(array);
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> convertToArrayList(String[] array) {
        ArrayList<String> convertedArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String element : array) {
            convertedArray.add(element);
        }

        return convertedArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `ArrayList` using [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org) (I'm one of the developers):

```
List<String> names = new StickyList<>(
  "Scott Fitzgerald", "Fyodor Dostoyevsky"
);
```

There is no guarantee that the object will actually be of class `ArrayList`. If you need that guarantee, do this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(
  new StickyList<>(
    "Scott Fitzgerald", "Fyodor Dostoyevsky"
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

*the lambda expression that generates a list of type* `ArrayList<Element>`
(1) without an unchecked cast
(2) without creating a second list (with eg. `asList()`)

`ArrayList<Element> list = Stream.of( array ).collect( Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ) );`

Answer (score 1):

With Stream (since java 16)

`new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(array).toList());`

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following helper method on occasions when I'm creating a ton of ArrayLists and need terse syntax:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> AL(T ...a) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(a));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var al = AL(AL(1, 2, 3, 4), AL(AL(5, 6, 7), AL(8, 9)));
        System.out.println(al); // => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [[5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]]
    }
}
```

[Guava uses the same approach](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/593b5963269abc2b32ee7f4d0bbc96d1539a7afa/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java#L102) so `@SafeVarargs` appears to be safe here. See also [Java SafeVarargs annotation, does a standard or best practice exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231037/java-safevarargs-annotation-does-a-standard-or-best-practice-exist).

Answer (score 1):

```
Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3)};

List<Element> list = List.of(array);
```

*or*

```
List<Element> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

both ways we can convert it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3)};
ArrayList<Element> list = (ArrayList) Arrays.asList(array);
```