# Initialization of an ArrayList in one line

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, initialization

I wanted to create a list of options for testing purposes. At first, I did this:

```
ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>();
places.add("Buenos Aires");
places.add("Córdoba");
places.add("La Plata");
```

Then, I refactored the code as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If this is intended for unit testing, try groovy out for a swing. You can write your test code in it while testing java code, and use `ArrasyList<String> places = ["Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"]`

Comment: In Java SE 7, you can substitute the parameterized type of the constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>): Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array

Comment: use double bracing initialization :)

Comment: It seems like you answered yourself in the question: ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>(asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata")); Arrays in Arrays.asList is not needed.

Comment: Stream.of("val1", "val2").collect(Collectors.toList()); //creates ArrayList, Java8 solution.

Comment: Why not just use String [] places = {"Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"); ?

Comment: @PaulSmith He might be interested in an elastic array that can grow dynamically. Your initialization will make **places** to have just three elements.

Comment: I don't understand why we cannot have some thing like `List<Integer> = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` in Java. Create and init a mutable array in one line, as I know Python and Swift could do that.

Answer (score 2232, accepted):

Actually, probably the "best" way to initialize the `ArrayList` is the method you wrote, as it does not need to create a new `List` in any way:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
```

The catch is that there is quite a bit of typing required to refer to that `list` instance.

There are alternatives, such as making an anonymous inner class with an instance initializer (also known as an "double brace initialization"):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("A");
    add("B");
    add("C");
}};
```

However, I'm not too fond of that method because what you end up with is a subclass of `ArrayList` which has an instance initializer, and that class is created just to create one object -- that just seems like a little bit overkill to me.

What would have been nice was if the [Collection Literals proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001193.html) for [Project Coin](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin) was accepted (it was slated to be introduced in Java 7, but it's not likely to be part of Java 8 either.):

```
List<String> list = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

Unfortunately it won't help you here, as it will initialize an immutable `List` rather than an `ArrayList`, and furthermore, it's not available yet, if it ever will be.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/ for more information about the double-brace initialization, pros and cons.

Comment: you don't need the second <String>.

Comment: @Delight The "diamond operator" was introduced in Java 7, which wasn't released when I wrote this answer back in 2009 ;)

Answer (score 2712):

It would be simpler if you were to just declare it as a `List` - does it have to be an ArrayList?

```
List<String> places = Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

Or if you have only one element:

```
List<String> places = Collections.singletonList("Buenos Aires");
```

This would mean that `places` is **immutable** (trying to change it will cause an `UnsupportedOperationException` exception to be thrown).

To make a mutable list that is a concrete `ArrayList` you can create an `ArrayList` from the immutable list:

```
ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"));
```

And import the correct package:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Comment: Yes, my class has an private ArrayList<String>.

Comment: @Marcase: Can you not change your class to use a List instead of ArrayList?

Comment: @Software Monkey: I wanted to know how to initialize an ArrayList. It's not real code, I was just testing things out. So, yes I might change it to List, but that would not answer my question.

Comment: As per my answer, if you're not using methods specific to `ArrayList`, it would be better design to change the declaration to `List`. Specify interfaces, not implementations.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström: if he changes the declaration to *List* and uses the *List<String> places = Arrays.asList(...);* he will not be able to use *places.add("blabla")*

Comment: @maks: True, except that's because of using `asList(...)`, not because of changing the declaration from `ArrayList` to `List`. I would put it as "he will not *need* to use `places.add("blabla")`". He already changed it to `asList(...)` himself.

Comment: Just to be clear, `asList(...)` returns a fixed size `List` that blows up on mutating operations like `remove` and `clear`, things the `List` contract claims to support. Even if you left declaration as `List`, you sill need to use `List l = new ArrayList(asList(...))` in order to get an object that doesn't throw OperationNotSupported exceptions. Liskov Substitution Principle anyone?

Comment: I find this answer slightly misleading, because it suggests that `Arrays.asList` returns something immutable.  That's not true.  It returns a list that can't be lengthened or shortened; but which can be mutated by swapping out an element for a new value.

Comment: How can it be that I need to lookup how to initialise a fucking mutable array every time I need to? And this is supposedly the best way? What an horrible language.

Answer (score 1134):

## The simple answer

### Java 9 or later:

```
List<String> strings = List.of("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

[`List.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable) will give you an *immutable* `List`, so it cannot be changed.
Which is what you want in most cases where you're prepopulating it.

This does not allow `null` elements.

### Java 8 or earlier:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

[`Arrays.asList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) will give you a `List`<sup>*</sup> backed by an array, so it cannot change length.
But you can call `List.set(...)`, so it's still *mutable*.

This does allow `null` elements.

<sup>*
<sub>Implementation detail: It's a private nested class inside `java.util.Arrays`, named `ArrayList`,

which is a different class from `java.util.ArrayList`, even though their simple names are the same.</sub></sup>

#### Static import

You can make Java 8 `Arrays.asList` even shorter with a static import:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;  
...
List<String> strings = asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

Any modern IDE<sup>*</sup> will suggest and do this for you.

I don't recommend statically importing the `List.of` method as just `of`, because it's confusing.

<sup>*
<sub>For example, in IntelliJ IDEA you press `Alt+Enter` and select `Static import method...`</sub></sup>

## Using `Stream`s

Why does it have to be a `List`?
With Java 8 or later you can use a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) which is more flexible:

```
Stream<String> strings = Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

You can concatenate `Stream`s:

```
Stream<String> strings = Stream.concat(Stream.of("foo", "bar"),
                                       Stream.of("baz", "qux"));
```

Or you can go from a `Stream` to a `List`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
...
var strings = Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz").toList(); // Java 16

List<String> strings = Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz").collect(toList()); // Java 8
```

But preferably, just use the `Stream` without collecting it to a `List`.

## If you specifically need a `java.util.ArrayList`<sup>*</sup>

If you want to *both* prepopulate an `ArrayList` *and* add to it afterwards, use

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(List.of("foo", "bar"));
```

or in Java 8 or earlier:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(asList("foo", "bar"));
```

or using `Stream`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;

List<String> strings = Stream.of("foo", "bar")
                             .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Then you can add to it after construction:

```
strings.add("baz");
```

But again, it's better to just use the `Stream` directly instead of collecting it to a `List`.

<sup>*<sub>You probably don't need specifically an `ArrayList`. To quote [JEP 269](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269):</sub></sup>

> <sub>There is a **small set** of use cases for initializing a mutable collection instance with a predefined set of values. It's usually preferable to have those predefined values be in an immutable collection, and then to initialize the mutable collection via a copy constructor.</sub>

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

### Program to interfaces, not to implementations

You said you've declared the list as an `ArrayList` in your code, but you should only do that if you're using some member of `ArrayList` that's not in `List`.

Which you are most likely not doing.

Usually you should just declare variables by the most general interface that you are going to use (e.g. `Iterable`, `Collection`, or `List`), and initialize them with the specific implementation (e.g. `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` or `Arrays.asList()`).

Otherwise you're limiting your code to that specific type, and it'll be harder to change when you want to.

For example, if you're passing an `ArrayList` to a `void method(...)`:

```
// Iterable if you just need iteration, for (String s : strings):
void method(Iterable<String> strings) { 
    for (String s : strings) { ... } 
}

// Collection if you also need .size(), .isEmpty(), or .stream():
void method(Collection<String> strings) {
    if (!strings.isEmpty()) { strings.stream()... }
}

// List if you also need random access, .get(index):
void method(List<String> strings) {
    strings.get(...)
}

// Don't declare a specific list implementation
// unless you're sure you need it:
void method(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    ??? // You don't want to limit yourself to just ArrayList
}
```

Another example would be always declaring variable an `InputStream` even though it is usually a `FileInputStream` or a `BufferedInputStream`, because one day soon you or somebody else will want to use some other kind of `InputStream`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that streams need to be closed whereas lists do not.

Comment: @MikeLowery: Are you thinking of `InputStream` and `OutputStream`? `java.util.stream.Stream` does not need to be closed. It does need a *terminal operation*, but you're not going to forget that, because without it the stream does nothing.

Comment: That's what I was actually working with, yes. But `java.util.stream.Stream` extends `BaseStream` which does have a `close()` method because it implements `AutoCloseable`. At the very least an IDE is going to complain about a potential resource leak.

Comment: @MikeLowery: You don't need to close Streams in general, and i haven't seen IntelliJ IDEA complain about me not doing so. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125169/why-is-java-8-stream-class-autocloseable

Comment: Eclipse does, provided you have it configured to find potential resource leaks. Personally I think it's confusing to have a class implement `AutoCloseable` when it may not need to actually be closed, but that's exactly what they did (see [API note](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)).

Comment: Also `Arrays.asList` allows passing null elements, while `List.of` doesn't.

Answer (score 122):

If you need a simple list of size 1:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.singletonList("A"));
```

If you need a list of several objects:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(strings,"A","B","C","D");
```

Answer (score 68):

With [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) you can write:

```
ArrayList<String> places = Lists.newArrayList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

In Guava there are also other useful static constructors. You can read about them [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this with just `java.util.Arrays` such as, `List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Beckah", "Sam", "Michael");`

Comment: @beckah method Arrays.asLists creates object of type List, while question is about creating ArrayList

Comment: [*This method is not actually very useful and will likely be deprecated in the future.*](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList-E...-)

Comment: @beckah `Arrays.asList` creates a list that can't be modified. If the list needs to be modified `Lists.newArrayList` will work and `Arrays.asList` won't.

Answer (score 48):

With [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) and above, as suggested in [JEP 269: Convenience Factory Methods for Collections](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269), creating an unmodifiable `List` instead of an `ArrayList` could be achieved using *collection literals* now with -

```
List<String> list = List.of("A", "B", "C");

Set<String> set = Set.of("A", "B", "C");
```

A similar approach would apply to `Map` as well -

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3")
```

which is similar to [Collection Literals proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001193.html) as stated by @coobird. Further clarified in the JEP as well -

---

**Alternatives**

> Language changes have been considered several times, and rejected:
>
> [Project Coin Proposal, 29 March 2009](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001112.html)
>
> [Project Coin Proposal, 30 March 2009](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001193.html)
>
> [JEP 186 discussion on lambda-dev, January-March 2014](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2014-January/011671.html)
>
> The language
> proposals were set aside in preference to a library-based proposal as
> summarized in this [message.](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2014-March/011938.html)

Related: [What is the point of overloaded Convenience Factory Methods for Collections in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918934/what-is-the-point-of-overloaded-convenience-factory-methods-for-collections-in-j/41918976#41918976)

Comment: Note that this creates an immutable `List` and not a modifiable `ArrayList`!

Comment: @xuiqzy precisely an *unmodifiable* one, if one was to mention

Answer (score 36):

Collection literals didn't make it into Java 8, but it is possible to use the Stream API to initialize a list in one rather long line:

```
List<String> places = Stream.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you need to ensure that your `List` is an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> places = Stream.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata").collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 34):

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

....

List<String> places = ImmutableList.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

Comment: I don't want to add a new dependency just to do that.

Comment: That's the same as `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"))`, which becomes `unmodifiableList(asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"))` with static imports. You don't need Google Collections for this.

Comment: No, it's not the same. As ImmutableList is documenting its immutability in the result type when unmodifiableList masquerades it  as a normal List.

Comment: Instead of the immutable one, google collections also offer mutable array list:
List<String> = Lists.newArrayList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");

Comment: You're going to pass that `ImmutableList` to other methods that take a `List`, and then you've lost that documentation anyway.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström No, you can still check its type at runtime, which can be useful.

Comment: @xuiqzy: Yes, but i was talking about in source code. Running extra code to check what type of List is being passed isn't what i call documentation. And if you're doing that you can just check if its a Collections.UnmodifiableList so the original point is moot anyway.

Answer (score 26):

You could create a factory method:

```
public static ArrayList<String> createArrayList(String ... elements) {
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (String element : elements) {
    list.add(element);
  }
  return list;
}

....

ArrayList<String> places = createArrayList(
  "São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Brasília");
```

But it's not much better than your first refactoring.

For greater flexibility, it can be generic:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> createArrayList(T ... elements) {
  ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
  for (T element : elements) {
    list.add(element);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Look back at the original post, it is asking for array initialization in *one line*, not 7 additional lines.

Comment: @LeoHolanda: Creating factory methods for every little thing is too much, I agree. But _depending_ on the situation, and on the number of times that that method is going to be used, it might make sense to create it. Creating extra abstraction layers is meant to _remove_ complexity, by creating more _meaningful_ methods that capture the _intent_ of the designer.

Comment: I think we can replace the enhanced `for` with `Collections.addAll(elements)` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238739/6243352).

Answer (score 14):

In Java 9 we can easily initialize an `ArrayList` in a single line:

```
List<String> places = List.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

or

```
List<String> places = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"));
```

This new approach of Java 9 has many advantages over the previous ones:

1. [Space Efficiency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-6A9BAE41-A1AD-4AA1-AF1A-A8FC99A14199)
2. [Immutability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-4F3E2B7D-CE90-4862-A78A-414FC08DA6E4)
3. [Thread Safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-DD066F67-9C9B-444E-A3CB-820503735951)

See this post for more details -> *[What is the difference between List.of and Arrays.asList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist)*

Comment: The first example does not create an `ArrayList`, despite the preceding sentence indicating that it does.

Answer (score 13):

Java 9 has the following method to create an *immutable* list as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) (or documented as *unmodifiable* [Java 10+](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of(E...))):

```
List<String> places = List.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

which is easily adapted to create a mutable list, if required:

```
List<String> places = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"));
```

Similar methods are available for `Set` and `Map`.

Please note that these methods do not accept `null` elements, a little bit hidden in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-):

> Throws:
> `NullPointerException` - if an element is `null` ...

Comment: Its good that you explicitly said "immutable list" and then showed another example of mutable list because it makes it clear which to use when.

Answer (score 10):

Simply use below code as follows.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("A");
            add("B");
            add("C");
}};
```

Comment: This is not one-line

Answer (score 8):

(Should be a comment, but too long, so new reply). As others have mentioned, the `Arrays.asList` method is fixed size, but that's not the only issue with it. It also doesn't handle inheritance very well. For instance, suppose you have the following:

```java
class A {}
class B extends A {}
    
public List<A> getAList() {
    return Arrays.asList(new B());
}
```

The above results in a compiler error, because `List<B>` (which is what is returned by `Arrays.asList`) is not a subclass of `List<A>`, even though you can add Objects of type `B` to a `List<A>` object.  To get around this, you need to do something like:

```
new ArrayList<A>(Arrays.<A>asList(b1, b2, b3))
```

This is probably the best way to go about doing this, especially if you need an unbounded list or need to use inheritance.

Comment: this is relevant only for Java versions previous to Java 8 (or even older) - the mentioned compiler error cannot be reproduced with Java 8 or later (example https://ideone.com/WHPY5d) - with not-so-old versions, the compiler is able to correctly infer the list type

Answer (score 8):

About the most compact way to do this is:

```
Double array[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Answer (score 8):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can write the following:

```
List<String> list = Lists.mutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

You can also be more specific about the types and whether they are Mutable or Immutable.

```
MutableList<String> mList = Lists.mutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
ImmutableList<String> iList = Lists.immutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

You can also do the same with Sets and Bags:

```
Set<String> set = Sets.mutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
MutableSet<String> mSet = Sets.mutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
ImmutableSet<String> iSet = Sets.immutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");

Bag<String> bag = Bags.mutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
MutableBag<String> mBag = Bags.mutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
ImmutableBag<String> iBag = Bags.immutable.with("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way:

```
List<String> values = Stream.of("One", "Two").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("2", "@2234", "21", "11");
```

Comment: Note that this creates an immutable List and not a modifiable ArrayList!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below statements:

#### Code Snippet:

```
String [] arr = {"Sharlock", "Homes", "Watson"};

List<String> names = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: You can inline first expression to have compact solution: `letters = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", "B", "C"});`

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways to create and initialize list in one line. Some examples:

```
//Using Double brace initialization, creates a new (anonymous) subclass of ArrayList
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>() {{ add("A");  add("B"); }};

//Immutable List
List<String> list2 = List.of("A", "B");

//Fixed size list. Can't add or remove element, though replacing the element is allowed.
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("A", "B");

//Modifiable list
List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));

//Using Java Stream, no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety
List<String> list5 = Stream.of("A", "B").collect(Collectors.toList());

//Thread safe List
List<String> list6 = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Like [Tom said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005089/1031312):

```
List<String> places = Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

But since you complained of wanting an ArrayList, you should first know that ArrayList is a subclass of List and you could simply add this line:

```
ArrayList<String> myPlaces = new ArrayList(places);
```

Although, that might make you complain about 'performance'.

In that case, it doesn't make sense to me, why, since your list is predefined it wasn't defined as an array (since the size is known at the time of initialization). And if that's an option for you:

```
String[] places = { "Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata" };
```

In case you don't care about the minor performance differences then you can also copy an array to an ArrayList very simply:

```
ArrayList<String> myPlaces = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(places));
```

Okay, but in the future, you need a bit more than just the place name, you need a country code too. Assuming this is still a predefined list that will never change during run-time, then it's fitting to use an `enum` set, which would require re-compilation if the list needed to be changed in the future.

```
enum Places { BUENOS_AIRES, CORDOBA, LA_PLATA }
```

would become:

```
enum Places {
    BUENOS_AIRES("Buenos Aires", 123),
    CORDOBA("Córdoba", 456),
    LA_PLATA("La Plata", 789);

    String name;
    int code;

    Places(String name, int code) {
      this.name = name;
      this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Enums have a static `values` method that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are declared, e.g.:

```
for (Places p : Places.values()) {
    System.out.printf("The place %s has code %d%n",
                  p.name, p.code);
}
```

In that case, I guess you wouldn't need your ArrayList.

P.S. [Randyaa demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238739/1031312) another nice way using the static utility method [Collections.addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. With the help of [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) you can initialize an immutable `List` (instead of an `ArrayList`) in one line:

```
List<String> strlist = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `StickyList` from [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org):

```
List<String> names = new StickyList<>(
  "Scott Fitzgerald", "Fyodor Dostoyevsky"
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");` is correct. but Any calls to `Arrays.asList()` with zero arguments or only one argument could be replaced with either a call to `Collections.singletonList()` or `Collections.emptyList()` which will save some memory.

Note: the list returned by `Collections.singletonList()` is immutable, while the list returned `Arrays.asList()` allows calling the `set()` method. This may break the code in rare cases.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this code line:

```
Collections.singletonList(provider)
```

Comment: Add a brief description of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can't do

```
ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"));
```

As was pointed out, you'd need to do a double brace initialization:

```
List<String> places = new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("x"); add("y"); }};
```

But this may force you into adding an annotation `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` or generate a serial UUID which is annoying. Also most code formatters will unwrap that into multiple statements/lines.

Alternatively you can do

```
List<String> places = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"x", "y" });
```

but then you may want to do a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Also according to javadoc you should be able to do this:

```
List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
```

But I'm not able to get it to compile with JDK 1.6.

Comment: Wrong! You *can* do the first line, and that is the right answer btw

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.singletonList(messageBody)
```

If you'd need to have a list of **one item**!

*Collections* is from *java.util* package.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it:

```
package main_package;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Stackkkk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        add(list, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
        System.out.println("I added " + list.size() + " element in one line");
    }

    public static void add(ArrayList<Object> list, Object... objects) {
        for (Object object : objects)
            list.add(object);
    }
}
```

Just create a function that can have as many elements as you want and call it to add them in one line.

Comment: If you go through all the trouble you might as well make it a template method instead of using plain `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

*interestingly no one-liner with the other overloaded* `Stream::collect` *method is listed*

```
ArrayList<String> places = Stream.of( "Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata" ).collect( ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll );
```

Comment: Totally different answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, `Arrays.asList()` is the best and most convenient one. I always like to initialize that way.
If you are a beginner in Java Collections then I would like you to refer [ArrayList initialization](http://www.gitarani.com/classified.htm?classifiedId=3011).

Comment: Why is Arrays.asList() better than creating a new ArrayList in one line with `add()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
// ArrayList
List<String> list = N.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
// HashSet
Set<String> set = N.asSet("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
// HashMap
Map<String, Integer> map = N.asMap("Buenos Aires", 1, "Córdoba", 2, "La Plata", 3);

// Or for Immutable List/Set/Map
ImmutableList.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
ImmutableSet.of("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
ImmutableSet.of("Buenos Aires", 1, "Córdoba", 2, "La Plata", 3);

// The most efficient way, which is similar with Arrays.asList(...) in JDK. 
// but returns a flexible-size list backed by the specified array.
List<String> set = Array.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

Declaration： I'm the developer of abacus-common.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a simple utility function that does this?

```
static <A> ArrayList<A> ll(A... a) {
  ArrayList l = new ArrayList(a.length);
  for (A x : a) l.add(x);
  return l;
}
```

"`ll`" stands for "literal list".

```
ArrayList<String> places = ll("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
```

Comment: you could use Collections.addAll instead of the for loop. Also, if you name the method `list`, the name requires no explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way : you can use this approach to add multiple elements to any type of collection like ArrayList and HashSet

```
ArrayList<String> allViews = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(allViews,"hello","world","abc","def","ghi");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the original question relates to a desire to declare and initialize the ArrayList in one line and avoid having to create separate code to acheive the initialization. Thus, the answer lies in the question but may be generalized as follows:

```
ArrayList&lt;AnyClass> arrayListOfAnyClass = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
  new AnyClass(param11, param12, ...),
  new AnyClass(param21, param22, ...),
  new AnyClass(param31, param32, ...),
  ...
));
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it's possible to do it in one line:

```
Arrays.asList(new MyClass[] {new MyClass("arg1"), new MyClass("arg2")})
```

Comment: May I ask what this adds to the question? This answer is already covered multiple times by other answers.

Comment: This is actually a really bad soluition as it creates an ABSTRACT LIST. You will not be able to add anything more to the container.

Answer (score -5):

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

This is the implementation of `Arrays.asList`, so you could go with

```
ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList("1", "2");
```

Comment: -1 Those are [not the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015980/arrays-aslist-confusing-source-code/12015999#12015999).