# Compact syntax for instantiating an initializing collection

Tags: java, collections, initialization

I'm looking for a compact syntax for instantiating a collection and adding a few items to it. I currently use this syntax:

```
Collection<String> collection = 
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "1", "2", "3" }));
```

I seem to recall that there's a more compact way of doing this that uses an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`, then adds the items in the subclass' constructor. However, I can't seem to remember the exact syntax.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

http://blog.firdau.si/2010/07/01/java-tips-initializing-collection/

```
List<String> s = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
```

Comment: Only works like that if you don't need the result to be extendable, though.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you're thinking about

```
collection = new ArrayList<String>() { // anonymous subclass
     { // anonymous initializer
         add("1");
         add("2");
         add("3");
     }
}
```

which, one comapcted, gives

```
collection = new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("1"); add("2"); add("3"); }}
```

FUGLY, to say the least. However, there is a variant to the Arrays.asList method : [`Arrays.asList(T...a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) which provides comapcity and readability. As an example, it gives the following line of code :

```
collection = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")); // yep, this one is the shorter
```

And notice you don't create an anonymous subclass of ArrayList of dubious use.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe that was

```
Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("foo");
    add("bar");
}};
```

Also known as double-bracket initialization.

Answer (score 5):

From **JDK9** you can use factory methods:

```
List<String> list = List.of("foo", "bar", "baz");
Set<String> set = Set.of("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

Comment: These are great methods but cannot be used for mutable collections.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an utility function:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> List<T> listOf(T ... values) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

So you could call it like:

```
collection = MyUtils.listOf("1", "2", "3");
```

That way, you can populate a list very easily, and still keep it mutable.

Answer (score 0):

See [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just me but I dont see the point of complicating things, purely in pursuit of writing shorter/faster code. Given the choice of typing marginally fewer lines of code and far easier debugging/revising I am pretty sure I'd choose the second option.

So unless there is a particular reason to push for keeping this short, I'd say stick to Ockham's razor, and given a number of solutions to a problem, go with the simplest one. That way when something does go wrong (which Murphy's law clearly dictates it will) you'll have a much easier time to track it. :)