# array of objects proper way of use?

Tags: java, android

What I have is

```
public static LinkedList<Mp3> musicList;        
...
if (musicList == null) {
    musicList = new LinkedList<Mp3>();
}//create... this works
```

but if I have like 5 or more lists how can I do something like this:

```
Object[] ob = new Object[]{musicList,musicList2,...,musicList10};

for (int i = 0; i < ob.length; i++){
    if (ob[i] == null) ob[i] = new LinkedList<Mp3>();
}
```

If I put it in first way it's working; how can I put it in like in second snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the references in the array will not change the original references used to create the array.

The references in the array are a copy of what was in the initialization.

What you should do is get rid of the musicListN variables and only have an array, or better yet use a List.

```
List<List<Mp3>> musicLists = new ArrayList<List<Mp3>>(LIST_COUNT);
for (int i = 0; i < LIST_COUNT; i++) {
  musicLists.add(new LinkedList<Mp3>());
}
```

Then use musicLists.get() to everywhere you would have used the older variables.

Comment: I implemented it in my code, but have 1 more question.. when i init LIST_COUNT = 5, it creates list of 10?
so when i look at musicLists.size() it is = 2xLIST_COUNT

Comment: @Hia Is the for loop running more then once.  You might need to add checks that the list is empty before initializing it.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid mixing arrays and generics.

Instead, consider this:

```
List<List<Mp3>> listsList = new ArrayList<List<Mp3>>();
listsList.add(new LinkedList<Mp3>());
```

Comment: thanks for answer! I will try this way.. but it seems instead of shortening my code I will make it longer :D

Comment: I ignored the part of how to initialize to make the concept of using only generic collections clearer, it might make it a bit longer, but it will make it better IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do one line object list initialization, look at this Q. [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)