# Arrays.asList() Confusing source code

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

According to [this source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/Arrays.java.html) for the `Arrays` class, the method `asList` passes an array to the constructor of new `ArrayList`. But there is no such constructor. Doesn't varargs generate an array, so how is this possible?

Here is the `asList` source:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList) is a different class than [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList).