# List.addAll throwing UnsupportedOperationException when trying to add another list

Tags: java

List.addAll throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` when trying to add another list.

```
List<String> supportedTypes = Arrays.asList("6500", "7600"};
```

and in loop I am doing,

```
supportedTypes.addAll(Arrays.asList(supportTypes.split(","))); //line 2
```

reading *supportTypes* from a file.

But line 2 throws a `UnsupportedOperationException`, but I am not able to determine why?

I am adding another list to a list, then why this operation is unsupported?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed sized list backed by an array, and you can't add elements to it.

You can create a modifiable list to make `addAll` work :

`List<String> supportedTypes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("6500", "7600", "8700"));`

Comment: @Batty - and that is the problem.  It doesn't work.  The javadoc for `asList` makes it clear that it won't work.  End of story.  You CANNOT add elements to a list created using `asList`.  Period.

Comment: List is an interface, the current implementation has to implement all its methods, but that implementation can throw an Exception to say "this method has no sense here"

Comment: I believe that stream().toList() has the same feature. This is what my issue was.

Answer (score 24):

This error also happens when the list is initialized with `Collections.emptyList()`, which is immutable:

```
List<String> myList = Collections.emptyList();
```

Instead, initialize it with a mutable list. For example

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 16):

Arrays.asList returns a fixed-size list.

If you to want be able to add elements to the list, do:

```
List<String> supportedTypes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("6500", "7600"});
supportedTypes.addAll(Arrays.asList(supportTypes.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 8):

Problem is that `Arrays.asList` method returns instance of [java.util.Arrays.ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList) which doesn't support add/remove operations on elements. It's not surprizing that `addAll` method throws exception because add method for `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` is defined as:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

**Related question:**

[Arrays.asList() Confusing source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015980/arrays-aslist-confusing-source-code)

**From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):**

> **Arrays.asList** returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this exception occured when I called `adapter.addAll(items)`, where `adapter` was a custom `ArrayAdapter`. This CustomAdapter had a parameter of type `Array` instead of `ArrayList`.