# What is the Syntax for creating Generic Arraylist in JDK12?

Tags: java, arraylist

Currently facing issue as "The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments " with the below Syntax

```
ArrayList<String> ls= new ArrayList<String>();
```

If i  try to use non generic type syntax , then it's giving me error while calling add method that add is not defined with the below code

```
ArrayList ls= new ArrayList();
ls.add("ABC");
```

Comment: These problems make it sound like you're importing the wrong `ArrayList` class, or that you've defined a class named `ArrayList` that is conflicting with the `java.util` one.

Comment: Thanks Louis, I have defined a class named Arraylist which was not allowing me to define generic statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your import statements to be sure that you are using the proper ArrayList as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015980/arrays-aslist-confusing-source-code/12015999#12015999).

Your code:

```
ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Is valid syntax for declaring an ArrayList.

Additionally, as @Louis Wasserman mentioned in a comment, be sure that you do not have any conflicting user-defined ArrayList classes.

The generic code:

```
ArrayList ls= new ArrayList();
ls.add("ABC");
```

Does not have many uses, you should always have a type for your array list as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207005/warning-arraylist-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-arrayliste-should).