# how to initialize static ArrayList<myclass> in one line

Tags: java

i have MyClass as

```
MyClass(String, String, int);
```

i know about how to add to add to ArrayList in this way:

```
MyClass.name = "Name";
MyClass.address = "adress";adress
MyClass.age = age;
```

then add to arrayList like:

```
list.add(MyClass);
```

but now i have many object MyClass in static form, i want to add

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>({"Name","Address", age};.....);
```

can i do like this. thank anyway

Comment: Classes in Java should be named like `MyClass`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use [double braces initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization): -

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>() {
    {
        add(new MyClass("name", "address", 23));
        add(new MyClass("name2", "address2", 45));
    }
};
```

As you can see that, `inner braces` is just like an `initializer` block, which is used to initialize the `list` in one go..

Also note the semi-colon at the end of your `double-braces`

Comment: This should really be List<MyClass> in the declaration

Comment: This is fun but in what is it better or simpler than just doing `list.add(new...` just after `List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>()` ?

Comment: does it need constructor of myclass like: myclass(string, string) in myclass?

Comment: @dystroy.. I have given a link to a post on SO, that describes everything about its pros and cons.. Just click on that link..

Comment: @NgoKy.. Well you can have any kind of constructor, and use it in this block.. That doesn't really matter.. But, ideally you should need to have at least a 1-arg constructor so that you can initialize your object here only (that is what you want).. Else you will need to iterate over your list to initialize `Object's` attribute..

Comment: But note, as the other post mentions, that this might introduce memory leaks. It creates a new anonymous inner class, which holds a reference to the containing object. Hence, if you have some reference to the list somewhere, without having an explicit reference to the containing object, the containing object still can't be garbage collected.

Answer (score 30):

You can do

```
List<MyClass> list = Arrays.asList(
                         new MyClass("Name", "Address", age),
                         // many more
                     );
```

Note: this will create a list where you can't change its size.

Comment: This works nicely for defining a constant (static final) array as a class member.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>(Arrays.asList(new MyClass[] {new MyClass("Name", "Address", age}));
```

Of course, your class must have a constructor like this:

```
public MyClass(String name, String address, int age) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can instantiate `ArrayList` like so:

```
new ArrayList<myclass>() {{
  add(new MyClass("Name", "Address", age));
}};
```

This creates an anonymous inner class that actually extends `ArrayList`, with an initialiser block that calls `add`.  This is obviously completely filthy and will make your colleagues want to hurt you, so you should use `Arrays.asList` instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is having the cleanest and simplest initialization, you might have this :

```
    List<MyClass> list = MyClass.build(
        "Name", "Address", 51,  
        "a2", "c", 4,
        "v", "d", 2
    );
```

This uses this utility method :

```
public static List<MyClass> build(Object... array) {
    List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<Test>();
    for (int i=0; i<array.length-2; i+=3) {
        list.add(new MyClass((String)array[i], (String)array[i+1], (Integer)array[i+2]));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way to do this in an effective way would be to :

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

 list.add(new MyClass("name", "address", 23));
 list.add(new MyClass("name2", "address2", 45));
```

although it requires a lot of typing but as you can clearly see this is more [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization)

Another alternative would be to use google [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) (not tested for efficiency):

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>(
           new MyClass("name", "address", 23), 
           new MyClass("name2", "address2", 45) );
```

The required import is `import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;`

also, you can use double braces initialization as originally proposed by @Rohit Jain: -

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>() {
    {
        add(new MyClass("name", "address", 23));
        add(new MyClass("name2", "address2", 45));
    }
};
```

As you can see that, `inner braces` is just like an `initializer` block, which is used to initialize the `list` in one go..

note the semi-colon at the end of your `double-braces`

also note the last method has some downsides as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line).