# Java's equivalent of static NSArray

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, android-studio

I am an iPhone programmer, trying to create an Android version of an iPhone app.

I have a NSArray in Objective C like below.

```
    NSArray *myarray =
@[
    @{@"name" : @"2014", @"items" :
          @[
              @{@"date" : @“01 January 2014", @"full_name" : @“Day 1”},
              @{@"date" : @“15 February 2014", @"full_name" : @"Day 2”},
           ]
    },
    @{@"name" : @"2015", @"items" :
          @[
              @{@"date" : @“05 January 2015", @"full_name" : @"Day 1"},
              @{@"date" : @“18 February 2015", @"full_name" : @"Day 2”},
              @{@"date" : @“26 March 2015", @"full_name" : @"Day 3”},
          ]
    }
];
```

What is Java equivalent of the array?
How can initialize the above array in Java?

I need all your help finding the answer, thanks.

Comment: Use a Java List or ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks @Chicken, i know basic initialization of Array List of String. But here i need ArrayList of Dictionary. How can i achieve this?

Comment: The current answer is the approach I would take. I don't know another way, sorry.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Chicken. I will try to use ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have two class like:

items class:

```
class item
{
   String date;
   String fullName;

   // getter and setter
}
```

and `Data` class:

```
class Data
{
 List<item> items;
 String name;

 // getter and setter
}
```

in your code you have one List of `Data` like:

```
List<Data> mArray = new ArrayList<Data>();
```

for adding as static see following link:

1 - [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

2- [how to initialize static ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670398/how-to-initialize-static-arraylistmyclass-in-one-line)

Comment: Thanks @Shayan, we can do this way, but it is a static array. It will not change at all. So, can we initialize this just like how i did using literals in Objective C?

Comment: Thanks @Shayan, i will follow your method of Data array, Thanks.