# Collectors.groupingBy into list of objects?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a list of TimeEntry objects I would like to group them into Day and Hour objects.

Where Day have list of Hour objects and the Hour have a list of TimeEntry objects for the hour it represents.

Day and Hour also keep a sum of the TimeEntry durations that's in their respective lists. If possible also get the day name into Day. The list of TimeEntry is sorted on "start".

```
public class TimeEntry {
  private LocalDateTime start;
  private Duration duration;

  public Integer getDay() { return this.start.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH); }
  public Integer getHour() { return this.start.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY); }
  public String getDayName() {
        return this.start.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault());
    }
}

public class Day {
  private Integer dayNr;
  private String dayName;
  private Duration sumOfHours;
  private List<Hour> hours;
}

public class Hour {
  private Integer hourNr;
  private Duration sumOfEntries;
  private List<TimeEntry> entries;
}
```

How do you do this with Java 8s' streams?

```
List<Day> days = timeEntries.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...?
```

Sample input:

```
List<TimeEntry> timeEntries = [{"2016-01-22 10:00", "5 minutes"}, 
{"2016-01-23 08:00", "7 minutes"} , {"2016-01-23 08:43", "3 minutes"}]
```

Sample output:

```
[
{dayNr: 22, dayName: Friday, sumofEntries: 5 minutes
  [{hourNr: 10, sumofEntries: 5 minutes}, 
    [{"2016-01-22 10:00", "5 minutes"}]} ]},
{dayNr: 23, dayName: Saturday, sumofEntries: 10 minutes
  [{hourNr: 8, sumofEntries: 10 minutes}, 
    [{"2016-01-23 08:00", "7 minutes"},
     {"2016-01-23 08:43", "3 minutes"} ]}
]
```

Comment: You won't get a `List<Day>` unless you write your _own_ collector. The best you can do with the core libraries is a `Map<Day, May<Hour, List<TimeEntry>>>` by doing a `groupingBy` on days and then, for each day, a `groupingBy` on hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite complicated operation. The direct way would be to first create a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<TimeEntry>>>` by grouping over the days, then over the hours. Once we have that map, we can postprocess it to create the wanted `List<Day>`.

Creating the temporary map is easy enough. We can use [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) where the classifier returns the day (through the method reference `TimeEntry::getDay`) and the downstream collector is another `groupingBy` collector that classifies over the hours (through the method reference `TimeEntry::getHour`). After this step, we have a map over each day where the value is a map over each hour mapping to the corresponding time entry.

Next, what we need to do is make a `List<Day>` out of that map. Basically, each entry of the map (so each day number) must be mapped to the corresponding `Day` object.

- The `dayNr` is simply the key of the entry.
- The `dayName` is the day name of one of the time entries for that day and an hour. One time entry must exist since we grouped by those fields earlier: to retrieve it, we get the hour map `Map<Integer, List<TimeEntry>>` for that day number and just keep the first value.
- The `hours` can be retrieved by manipulating the hour map `Map<Integer, List<TimeEntry>>` for that day number. For each entry of that map:

  - The `hourNr` is simply the key of the entry
  - The `entries` field is the value of the entry
  - The `sumOfEntries` is the addition of all the duration of the time entries for that hour number.
- Finally, the `sumOfHours` is the addition of all the `sumOfEntries` for each hour number for that day number.

A complete implementation is the following, where it is assumed that all of your domain objects have an appropriate constructor and the appropriate getters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    List<TimeEntry> timeEntries = Arrays.asList(
        new TimeEntry(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-01-22 10:00", formatter), Duration.ofMinutes(5)),
        new TimeEntry(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-01-23 08:00", formatter), Duration.ofMinutes(7)),
        new TimeEntry(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-01-23 08:43", formatter), Duration.ofMinutes(3))
    );

    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<TimeEntry>>> map = 
        timeEntries.stream()
                   .collect(groupingBy(TimeEntry::getDay, groupingBy(TimeEntry::getHour)));

    List<Day> output =
        map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .map(e -> {
              String dayName = e.getValue().values().iterator().next().get(0).getDayName();
              List<Hour> hours =
                 e.getValue().entrySet()
                             .stream()
                             .map(he -> new Hour(he.getKey(), sumDuration(he.getValue(), TimeEntry::getDuration), he.getValue()))
                             .collect(toList());
              return new Day(e.getKey(), dayName, sumDuration(hours, Hour::getSumOfEntries), hours);
           })
           .collect(toList());

    System.out.println(output);
}

private static <T> Duration sumDuration(List<T> list, Function<T, Duration> function) {
    return list.stream().map(function::apply).reduce(Duration.ofMinutes(0), (d1, d2) -> d1.plus(d2));
}
```

Note that the addition of `Duration` objects from a list was factored into a helper method `sumDuration`.

Output of the sample above (assuming a `toString()` printing all the fields enclosed in square brackets):

```
[Day [dayNr=22, dayName=vendredi, sumOfHours=PT5M, hours=[Hour [hourNr=10, sumOfEntries=PT5M, entries=[TimeEntry [start=2016-01-22T10:00, duration=PT5M]]]]], Day [dayNr=23, dayName=samedi, sumOfHours=PT10M, hours=[Hour [hourNr=8, sumOfEntries=PT10M, entries=[TimeEntry [start=2016-01-23T08:00, duration=PT7M], TimeEntry [start=2016-01-23T08:43, duration=PT3M]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't write all the code for you, but this would implement Boris The Spider's idea and hopefully get you started. After instantiating your TimeEntry list like so (See [how to initialize static ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670398/how-to-initialize-static-arraylistmyclass-in-one-line)):

```
List<TimeEntry> timeEntries = new ArrayList<TimeEntry>() {
    {
        add(new TimeEntry("2016-01-22T10:00", "PT5M"));
        add(new TimeEntry("2016-01-23T08:00", "PT7M"));
        add(new TimeEntry("2016-01-23T08:43", "PT3M"));
    }
};
```

then you `stream` it. You will need two `groupingBy` collectors. The first will group by hours:

```
Collector<TimeEntry, ?, Map<Integer, List<TimeEntry>>> groupingByHours
    = Collectors.groupingBy(TimeEntry::getHour);
```

and the second will group by days.

```
Collector<TimeEntry, ?, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<TimeEntry>>>> groupingByDaysByHour
    = Collectors.groupingBy(TimeEntry::getDay, groupingByHours);
```

You can then get your `TimeEntry` list grouped by days then hours like so:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<TimeEntry>>> dayMap = 
    timeEntries.stream()
    .collect( groupingByDaysByHour);
```

This will give the output of:

```
{22={10=[2016-01-22T10:00 PT5M]}, 23={8=[2016-01-23T08:00 PT7M, 2016-01-23T08:43 PT3M]}}
```

For completeness sake, your original `TimeEntry` class modified to work with this example:

```
class TimeEntry {
    private LocalDateTime start;
    private Duration duration;

    public TimeEntry(String start, String duration) {
        this.start = LocalDateTime.parse(start, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        this.duration = Duration.parse(duration);
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return start.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    public int getHour() {
        return start.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    }
    public long getDuration() {
        return duration.toMinutes();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return start.toString() + " " + duration.toString();
    }
}
```