# How do I enter parameters for an ArrayList in BlueJ?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

In BlueJ, if I write a method that takes an array as a parameter, then when I want to test that method with a method call I have to enter the elements with curly braces, so:

{1,2,3}

How do I do a method call for an `ArrayList`?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test2{

    public static int[] toArray(ArrayList<Integer>a){
        int len = a.size();
        int []b = new int[len];
        for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
            b[i] = a.get(i);
        }
     return b;    

    }
}
```

Now I want to test it in BlueJ, what should I type in the following dialog box?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Simon, I have read that link now, but its not exactly what I am asking, please see my edit to clarify.

Comment: @Maroun, I have added more details

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an instance of `ArrayList` to pass to your method when you call it.  With your project open in the main BlueJ window, click on the Tools menu, then on "Use Library Class...", then select `java.util.ArrayList` from the Class menu.  Also select the no-argument constructor from the list that appears, then click Ok.

[image: BlueJ Call Library Class dialog]

BlueJ will then display another dialog asking you for a name for the instance and for a type parameter for the `ArrayList`.  Enter a name and `Integer` for the type parameter.

[image: BlueJ Create Object dialog]

After you click Ok, the new `ArrayList` instance will appear in the object bench area at the bottom of the main BlueJ window.

[image: BlueJ Object Bench]

When you right click on the new instance, BlueJ will display a menu of methods that can be called on it.  Select the `boolean add(Integer)` method a few times to add some values to the instance.

[image: Add Integers to the ArrayList]

Finally, when you right click on your test class and call the `toArray` method, you can enter the name of the `ArrayList` instance to pass it as the argument to your method.

[image: BlueJ Method Call dialog]

The results of the method call are displayed in a dialog.

[image: BlueJ Method Results dialog]

Click the Inspect button to view the contents of the `int` array returned from your method, or click the Get button to add it to the object bench.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
```

Will return a `List` and not a `ArrayList`.

Your methods' parameters should always be the interface and not the implementation.