# Why use an ArrayList as a constructor parameter in Java (BlueJ)?

Tags: java, arraylist, parameters, constructor, bluej

I'm trying to complete an assignment in BlueJ for uni and I've hit a snag at the first hurdle.

In the assignment, we are given a class, as well as the names of the constructor, methods, and parameters of that class. We're not allowed to change these because the assignments are partially marked by a test unit (or something to that effect).

One of the constructors for this class is given as

```
 public class PlayList
 {
    public PlayList(String name, ArrayList<Track> tracks) {
    }
```

And I have (partially) completed it as

```
public class PlayList
{
   private String listName;
   private ArrayList<Track> listTracks = new ArrayList<Track>();

   /**
    * Constructs a playlist with a title and an ArrayList of tracks
    * 
    * @param name The name of the playlist
    * @param tracks An ArrayList of tracks in the playlist
    */
   public PlayList(String name, ArrayList<Track> tracks) {
       listName = name;
       //I really don't know what to do with the tracks parameter yet
   }
```

Okay, so, I know from this question ([How do I enter parameters for an ArrayList in BlueJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018998/how-do-i-enter-parameters-for-an-arraylist-in-bluej)) that I have to create an instance of an ArrayList in order to pass it as a parameter in BlueJ.

What I don't understand is *why* - why have they used `ArrayList<Track>` as a parameter for the constructor? What is the benefit of doing this?

(I figure there must be a benefit to doing it like this (if there wasn't the functionality wouldn't exist in the first place), but I don't understand *what* it is, and if someone could explain it to me, I'd be greatly appreciative.)

Comment: It's quite clear. If you have a list of tracks, you can create a playlist by passing the name and the list to `Playlist`. If you just pass the name, you'll have to add the tracks separately, which can be unnecessary extra code if you already have the list of tracks you want to include.

Comment: A PlayList is a list of tracks to play, and a name. So it's quite natural to pass the name and the list of tracks to play when constructing the PlayList. It should be a List<Track> rather than an ArrayList<Track>, but that's another matter. What to do with thelist? The same thing you did with the name: initialize (listTracks) a field with the list of tracks passed as argument.

Comment: @Kayaman But can't the same thing be achieved by just creating tracks and then adding them to the playlist using `tracks.add(track1)`?

Comment: @Prussan Of course. But unless you're getting paid by lines of code, you probably shouldn't write excessively verbose code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why have they used `ArrayList<Track>` as a parameter for the constructor?

They did it to allow callers to pass an arbitrary number of `Track`s in a single parameter.

Java offers several options to do this: you could pass a collection, an array, or even an iterator. If I were designing a signature for the constructor, I would strongly prefer `Collection<Track>` or at least a `List<Track>` to `ArrayList<Track>`, in order to give callers more options as far as what collection they could pass to my constructor.

Going back to what to do with the array list, you should make a *defensive copy* of it. One way would be using `Collections.copy`, like this:

```
Collections.copy(this.tracks, tracks);
```

Once the copy is complete, you should walk through elements of `this.track`, and ensure that they are not `null`.

Comment: or `listTracks.addAll(tracks)` to copy the tracks into its own collection.

Comment: Right, so essentially, doing this avoids all the rigmarole of having to add each track to the ArrayList individually. I wish they'd mentioned this in class!