# Initializing ArrayList with some predefined values

Tags: java

I have an sample program as shown.

I want my `ArrayList` `symbolsPresent` to be initialized with some predefined symbols: ONE, TWO, THREE, and FOUR.

```
symbolsPresent.add("ONE");
symbolsPresent.add("TWO");
symbolsPresent.add("THREE");
symbolsPresent.add("FOUR");
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    private ArrayList<String> symbolsPresent = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getSymbolsPresent() {
        return symbolsPresent;
    }

    public void setSymbolsPresent(ArrayList<String> symbolsPresent) {
        this.symbolsPresent = symbolsPresent;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println("Symbols Present is" + t.symbolsPresent);

    }    
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Add them in a Constructor.

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line

Comment: better fit for an enum here?

Answer (score 167):

try this

```
new String[] {"One","Two","Three","Four"};
```

or

```
List<String> places = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");
```

[**ARRAYS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: good solution, asList(...) returns new ArrayList<>(a) like the question's author requested

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueRodriguez asList(...) returns List<E> not ArrayList<E>

Comment: @PermGenError List is the return type, the method returns ArrayList. It's not java.util.ArrayList, it's an internal class with the same behavior

Comment: The list returned by `Arrays.asList(T...)` is capped in size to the size of the array supplied in the constructor. That may or may not be an issue, depending on usage.

Answer (score 59):

Double brace initialization is an option:

```
List<String> symbolsPresent = new ArrayList<String>() {{
   add("ONE");
   add("TWO");
   add("THREE");
   add("FOUR");
}};
```

Note that the `String` generic type argument *is* necessary in the assigned expression as indicated by [JLS §15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)

> It is a compile-time error if a class instance creation expression declares an anonymous class using the "<>" form for the class's type arguments.

Comment: interesting anonymous innterclass!

Comment: If you add an object that was defined outside of this structure, you'll need to declare it `final` in order for it to compile. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class) if you want to know why.

Comment: There's also a [performance penalty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization), although it's significance is debatable.

Comment: this is cool, but in Java 7 you can avoid specifying the type in the initialization: here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Comment: @Rose that link only details standard `List` initialization, i.e. no anonymous inner class with values being added :)

Comment: @Reimeus my point is that instead of List<String> symbolsPresent = new ArrayList<String>() ..... you can do List<String> symbolsPresent = new ArrayList<>()

Comment: that is an empty `List` which is not what the OP wanted...

Answer (score 21):

How about using [**overloaded ArrayList constructor**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
 private ArrayList<String> symbolsPresent = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"One","Two","Three","Four"}));
```

Comment: wouldn't Arrays.asList() alone do the job?

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueRodriguez it would, but then you will have to have List<String> on the left side. :)

Comment: Note that you can use the var-args syntax with Java 5 and later.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, if you use Arrays.asList() and use directly the returned List, it would be fixed size. Basically it would still behave like an array, just wrapped in List interface.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the varargs syntax to make your code cleaner:

Use the overloaded constructor:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

Subclass ArrayList in a utils module:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public MyArrayList(T... values) {
        super(Arrays.asList(values));
    }
}

ArrayList<String> list = new MyArrayList<String>("a", "b", "c");
```

Or have a static factory method (my preferred approach):

```
public class Utils {
  public static <T> ArrayList<T> asArrayList(T... values) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(values));
  }
}

ArrayList<String> list = Utils.asArrayList("a", "b", "c");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

...


ArrayList<String> getSymbolsPresent = Lists.newArrayList("item 1", "item 2");

...
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use ***[Java 8 Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)***.
You can create a Stream of objects and collect them as a List.

```
private List<String> symbolsPresent = Stream.of("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR")
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Voted up because streams provide a uniform mechanism for addressing a wide range of problems whereas the custom functions simply chew up mortal memory.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static final List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("public_profile");
    add("email");
    add("user_birthday");
    add("user_about_me");
    add("user_location");
    add("user_likes");
    add("user_posts");
}};
```

Answer (score 4):

Java 9 allows you to create an unmodifiable list with a single line of code using `List.of` factory:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> examples = List.of("one", "two", "three");
        System.out.println(examples);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[one, two, three]
```

Answer (score 3):

Personnaly I like to do all the initialisations in the constructor

```
public Test()
{
  symbolsPresent = new ArrayList<String>();
  symbolsPresent.add("ONE");
  symbolsPresent.add("TWO");
  symbolsPresent.add("THREE");
  symbolsPresent.add("FOUR");
}
```

Edit : It is a choice of course and others prefer to initialize in the declaration. Both are valid, I have choosen the constructor because all type of initialitions are possible there (if you need a loop or parameters, ...). However I initialize the constants in the declaration on the top on the source.
The most important is to follow a rule that you like and be consistent in our classes.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you want to enforce the List to be read-only (throws a UnsupportedOperationException if modified):

`List<String> places = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three"));`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use Arrays.asList() for single line initialization. For different ways of declaring and initializing a List you can also refer [Initialization of ArrayList in Java](http://www.gitarani.com/classified.htm?classifiedId=3011)

Answer (score 1):

I use a generic class that inherit from ArrayList and implement a constructor with a parameter with variable number or arguments :

```
public class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public MyArrayList(T...items){
        for (T item : items) {
            this.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
MyArrayList<String>myArrayList=new MyArrayList<String>("s1","s2","s2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to initialize outside of any method then use the initializer blocks :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
private ArrayList<String> symbolsPresent = new ArrayList<String>();

// All you need is this block.
{
symbolsPresent = new ArrayList<String>();
symbolsPresent.add("ONE");
symbolsPresent.add("TWO");
symbolsPresent.add("THREE");
symbolsPresent.add("FOUR");
}


public ArrayList<String> getSymbolsPresent() {
    return symbolsPresent;
}

public void setSymbolsPresent(ArrayList<String> symbolsPresent) {
    this.symbolsPresent = symbolsPresent;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {    
    Test t = new Test();
    System.out.println("Symbols Present is" + t.symbolsPresent);

}    
}
```