# Profanity Test Not Working As Expected (In Chat Application)?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, contains

I am trying to create a profanity test for my app, but it seems to malfunction!! why?

code:

```
public boolean filter(String message)
{

    String[] words={*CUSS WORDS*};

    for(int i=0; i< (words.length-1); i++ )
    {
        if(message.indexOf(words[i].toLowerCase())!= -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

OR Another code (BUT SAME FUNCTION):

```
public boolean filter(String message)
{

    String[] words={CUSS WORDS};

    for(int i=0; i< (words.length-1); i++ )
    {
        if(message.contains(words[i}))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So the PROBLEM IS:
I tried these 2 pieces of codes with similar results. For example for "**Fuck**", if I enter "**fu**" into my app it stops it from being entered or for "**ass**", if I enter "**as**" it stop it from being entered! (*Filter works to stop any profanity from entering the chat*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your curse words in a set, then break up the users sentence into individual words. Check each word to see if it's in your set of curse words.

```
public boolean curse(String str){
    //Create your set here
   HashSet<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>();

    //Use it's add function to add your curse words
    wordSet.add("ass");

    String array[] = str.split(" ");

    for(String s : array){
        if(wordSet.contains(s.toLowerCase()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Comment: I was wondering how would I make the map of the curse words (Would it be possible for you to also give me an example) please if you dont mind. Thank You

Comment: why a map?  maybe a List or a Set

Comment: @Elroy Jetson     It did not work!!!! I did this:String[] words={"",",etc"};
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
        //HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
        String array[] = message.split(" ");
        for(String s : array){
            if(stringList.contains(s))
                return true;
        }
        return false;                                                                                  The string array has so many curse words!

Comment: Thank You Guys Your Code Really Helped and Now It Works! Thank You So Much

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because of my reputation, but, continuing Elroy Jetson's answer, you initialize the HashSet using Arrays.asList, as is described here in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16194967/2836264. The HashMap constructor takes in this case a `List<String>`, that is created from the `String[]`.

```
String[] cussArray = {"fuck", "shit", "brocolli"};
HashSet<String> cussSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(cussArray));
```