# Double array initialization in Java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, double

I was reading a book on [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) and came across an example in which an array of type double was initialized in a way that I haven't seen before. What type of initialization is it and where else can it be used?

```
double m[][]={
    {0*0,1*0,2*0,3*0},
    {0*1,1*1,2*1,3*1},
    {0*2,1*2,2*2,3*2},
    {0*3,1*3,2*3,3*3}
};
```

Comment: i think `.` in the first statement should be a `,`

Comment: Your code won't compile as such. The dot should be a comma.

Comment: To define a double, the * char must be . char

Comment: @fujy: This is just a multiplication table. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: If the book showed an example, then surely it'd explain how and why and when it is used.

Comment: Yes, but I think he is trying to define a double here, where would be the double example if it was multiplication?

Comment: @fujy: maybe it comes afterwards, maybe it really doesn't matter for the purposes of this question!

Comment: The , is a mistake on my part. And thanks for the replies. I was over stressing my mind and thinking of it as some sort of special initialization.

Answer (score 39):

This is *array initializer syntax*, and it can only be used on the right-hand-side when declaring a variable of array type. Example:

```
int[] x = {1,2,3,4};
String[] y = {"a","b","c"};
```

If you're not on the RHS of a variable declaration, use an array constructor instead:

```
int[] x;
x = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
String[] y;
y = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
```

These declarations have the exact same effect: a new array is allocated and constructed with the specified contents.

In your case, it might actually be clearer (less repetitive, but a bit less concise) to specify the table programmatically:

```
double[][] m = new double[4][4];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        m[i][j] = i*j;
    }
}
```

Comment: I felt the presence of a zen master there. I see slightly more clearly now ;-)

Comment: Presumably something convoluted like this would be how to assign to the double double using constructor syntax `  double[][] m;
  m = new double[][] {
    new double[] { 0 * 0, 1 * 0, 2 * 0, 3 * 0 },
    new double[] { 0 * 1, 1 * 1, 2 * 1, 3 * 1 },
    new double[] { 0 * 2, 1 * 2, 2 * 2, 3 * 2 },
    new double[] { 0 * 3, 1 * 3, 2 * 3, 3 * 3 }
  };`

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize an array by writing actual values it holds in curly braces on the right hand side like:

```
String[] strArr = { "one", "two", "three"};
int[] numArr = { 1, 2, 3};
```

In the same manner two-dimensional array or **array-of-arrays holds an array as a value**, so:

```
String strArrayOfArrays = { {"a", "b", "c"}, {"one", "two", "three"} };
```

Your example shows exactly that

```
double m[][] = {
    {0*0,1*0,2*0,3*0},
    {0*1,1*1,2*1,3*1},
    {0*2,1*2,2*2,3*2},
    {0*3,1*3,2*3,3*3}
};
```

But also the multiplication of number will also be performed and its the same as:

```
double m[][] = { {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 6, 9} };
```

Answer (score 1):

`double m[][]` declares an array of arrays, so called multidimensional array.

`m[0]` points to an array in the size of four, containing 0*0,1*0,2*0,3*0.
Simple math shows the values are actually 0,0,0,0.

Second line is also array in the size of four, containing 0,1,2,3.

And so on...

I guess this mutiple format in you book was to show that 0*0 is row 0 column 0, 0*1 is row 0 column 1, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now realise that it was a pretty simple initialization.

Answer (score 1):

It is called an array initializer and can be explained in the [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) [specification 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6).

This can be used to initialize any array, but it can only be used for initialization (not assignment to an existing array). One of the unique things about it is that the dimensions of the array can be determined from the initializer. Other methods of creating an array require you to manually insert the number. In many cases, this helps minimize trivial errors which occur when a programmer modifies the initializer and fails to update the dimensions.

Basically, the initializer allocates a correctly sized array, then goes from left to right evaluating each element in the list. The specification also states that if the element type is an array (such as it is for your case... we have an array of double[]), that each element may, itself be an initializer list, which is why you see one outer set of braces, and each line has inner braces.

Comment: ["Doubt" for the rest of us.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question/4183#4183)

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept Double Objects than this post is helpful:
[Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

```
List<Double> y = Arrays.asList(null, 1.0, 2.0);
Double x = y.get(1);
```