# Why is Java 8 Stream class AutoCloseable?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8, the Stream class implements AutoCloseable. This means that a stream instance should be closed explicitly.

I understand why file handlers and DB connections are closeable. But why streams?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think the current [documentation/javadoc of Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is pretty clear:

> Streams have a BaseStream.close() method and implement AutoCloseable,
>   but nearly all stream instances do not actually need to be closed
>   after use. Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such
>   as those returned by Files.lines(Path, Charset)) will require closing.
>   Most streams are backed by collections, arrays, or generating
>   functions, which require no special resource management. (If a stream
>   does require closing, it can be declared as a resource in a
>   try-with-resources statement.)