# Java 8 Streams and try with resources

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I thought that the stream API was here to make the code easier to read.
I found something quite annoying. The `Stream` interface extends the `java.lang.AutoCloseable` interface.

So if you want to correctly close your streams, you have to use try with resources.

*Listing 1*. Not very nice, streams are not closed.

```
public void noTryWithResource() {
    Set<Integer> photos = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    @SuppressWarnings("resource") List<ImageView> collect = photos.stream()
        .map(photo -> new ImageView(new Image(String.valueOf(photo))))
        .collect(Collectors.<ImageView>toList());
}
```

*Listing 2*. With 2 nested try

```
public void tryWithResource() {
    Set<Integer> photos = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    try (Stream<Integer> stream = photos.stream()) {
        try (Stream<ImageView> map = stream
                .map(photo -> new ImageView(new Image(String.valueOf(photo)))))
        {
            List<ImageView> collect = map.collect(Collectors.<ImageView>toList());
        }
    }
}
```

*Listing 3*. As `map` returns a stream, both the `stream()` and the `map()` functions have to be closed.

```
public void tryWithResource2() {
    Set<Integer> photos = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    try (Stream<Integer> stream = photos.stream(); Stream<ImageView> map = stream.map(photo -> new ImageView(new Image(String.valueOf(photo)))))
    {
        List<ImageView> collect = map.collect(Collectors.<ImageView>toList());
    }
}
```

The example I give does not make any sense. I replaced `Path` to jpg images with `Integer`, for the sake of the example. But don't let you distract by these details.

What is the best way to go around with those auto closable streams.
I have to say I'm not satisfied with any of the 3 options I showed.
What do you think? Are there yet other more elegant solutions?

Comment: You had no syntactic reason to nest try within try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Java 8 Stream class AutoCloseable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125169/why-is-java-8-stream-class-autocloseable)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're using `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` which presumably suppresses a warning about an unclosed resource. This isn't one of the warnings emitted by `javac`. Web searches seem to indicate that Eclipse issues warnings if an `AutoCloseable` is left unclosed.

This is a reasonable warning according to the [Java 7 specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) that introduced `AutoCloseable`:

> A resource that must be closed when it is no longer needed.

However, the [Java 8 specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) for `AutoCloseable` was relaxed to remove the "must be closed" clause. It now says, in part,

> An object that may hold resources ... until it is closed.
>
> It is possible, and in fact common, for a base class to implement AutoCloseable even though not all of its subclasses or instances will hold releasable resources. For code that must operate in complete generality, or when it is known that the AutoCloseable instance requires resource release, it is recommended to use try-with-resources constructions. However, when using facilities such as Stream that support both I/O-based and non-I/O-based forms, try-with-resources blocks are in general unnecessary when using non-I/O-based forms.

This issue was discussed extensively within the Lambda expert group; [this message](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-August/002195.html) summarizes the decision. Among other things it mentions changes to the `AutoCloseable` specification (cited above) and the `BaseStream` specification (cited by other answers). It also mentions the possible need to adjust the Eclipse code inspector for the changed semantics, presumably not to emit warnings unconditionally for `AutoCloseable` objects. Apparently this message didn't get to the Eclipse folks or they haven't changed it yet.

In summary, if Eclipse warnings are leading you into thinking that you need to close all `AutoCloseable` objects, that's incorrect. Only certain specific `AutoCloseable` objects need to be closed. Eclipse needs to be fixed (if it hasn't already) not to emit warnings for all `AutoCloseable` objects.

Answer (score 16):

You only need to close Streams if the stream needs to do any cleanup of itself, usually I/O.  Your example uses an HashSet so it doesn't need to be closed.

from the [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) javadoc:

> Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such as those returned by Files.lines(Path, Charset)) will require closing. Most streams are backed by collections, arrays, or generating functions, which require no special resource management.

So in your example this should work without issue

```
List<ImageView> collect = photos.stream()
                       .map(photo -> ...)
                       .collect(toList());
```

**EDIT**

Even if you need to clean up resources, you should be able to use just one try-with-resource.  Let's pretend you are reading a file where each line in the file is a path to an image:

```
 try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file)){
       List<ImageView> collect = lines
                                  .map(line -> new ImageView( ImageIO.read(new File(line)))
                                  .collect(toList());
  }
```

Comment: This is my point. The Set does not need to be closed. But the API requires(sort of) it to be closed.

Answer (score 12):

“Closeable” means “can be closed”, not “must be closed”.

That was true in the past, e.g. see [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html):

> Closing a `ByteArrayOutputStream` has no effect.

And that is true now for `Stream`s where the [documentation makes clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip.navbar.top):

> Streams have a `BaseStream.close()` method and implement `AutoCloseable`, but nearly all stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use. Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such as those returned by `Files.lines(Path, Charset)`) will require closing.

So if an audit tool generates false warnings, it’s a problem of the audit tool, not of the API.

Note that even if you want to add resource management, there is no need to nest `try` statements. While the following is sufficient:

```
final Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "COPYRIGHT");
try(Stream<String> stream=Files.lines(p, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {
    System.out.println(stream.filter(s->s.contains("Oracle")).count());
}
```

you may also add the secondary `Stream` to the resource management without an additional `try`:

```
final Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "COPYRIGHT");
try(Stream<String> stream=Files.lines(p, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    Stream<String> filtered=stream.filter(s->s.contains("Oracle"))) {
    System.out.println(filtered.count());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to create a utility method that reliably closes streams with a try-with-resource-statement.

It is a bit like a try-finally that is an *expression* (something that is the case in e.g. Scala).

```
/**
 * Applies a function to a resource and closes it afterwards.
 * @param sup Supplier of the resource that should be closed
 * @param op operation that should be performed on the resource before it is closed
 * @return The result of calling op.apply on the resource 
 */
private static <A extends AutoCloseable, B> B applyAndClose(Callable<A> sup, Function<A, B> op) {
    try (A res = sup.call()) {
        return op.apply(res);
    } catch (RuntimeException exc) {
        throw exc;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrapped in applyAndClose", exc);
    }
}
```

<sup>(Since resources that need to be closed often also throw exceptions when they are allocated non-runtime exceptions are wrapped in runtime exceptions, avoiding the need for a separate method that does that.)</sup>

With this method the example from the question looks like this:

```
Set<Integer> photos = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

List<ImageView> collect = applyAndClose(photos::stream, s -> s
    .map(photo -> new ImageView(new Image(String.valueOf(photo))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This is useful in situations when closing the stream is required, such as when using `Files.lines`. It also helps when you have to do a "double close", as in your example in *Listing 3*.

<sup>*This answer is an adaptation of an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22923414/452775) to a similar question.*</sup>