# Are non-parallel Streams meant to do an operation in mass on big amount of data?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

A few weeks ago, I was searching for a way to extract some specific value from a file and stumbled on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791138/find-pattern-in-files-with-java-8) which introduced me to the `Stream` Object.

My first instinct was to investigate if this object would help with other file operations, such as replacing several placeholders with corresponding values for which I used `BufferedReader` and `FileWriter`. I failed miserably at producing any working code, but since then I began taking interest on articles which covered the subject, so I could understand the intended use of `Stream`.

On the way, I stumbled upon `Optional` and came to a good understanding of it and can now identify the cases where I am comfortable using `Optional` while maintaining my code clean and understandable. However, I can't say this is the case for `Stream`, not mentioning that it [may not have provided the performance gain I imagined it would bring](https://blog.codefx.org/java/stream-performance/) and [will still need a `finally` clause in cases where IO is involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125169/why-is-java-8-stream-class-autocloseable).

Here is the main issue I've been trying to wrap my head around, keeping in mind that I mostly worked on one-thread programming until now: When is it prefered to use a `Stream` aside from parallel processing?

Is it to do an operation in bulk on a specific subset of a big collection of data, where `Collection` would have been used when trying to access and manipulate specific objects of the said collection? Although it seems to be the intended use, I'm still not sure that the example I linked at the beginning of my question is your typical use case.

Or is it only a construct used to make the code smaller thanks to lambda expression at the sacrifice of readability? (Nothing against lambda if used correctly, but most of the example of `Stream` usage I saw where quite illegible, which didn't help for my general understanding)

Comment: I could show you a couple of examples at our workplace, where we have re-factored some code to stream-api vs plain loops, it is *literally* 10 times shorter and IMO way more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always referred to the description on the [Java 8 Streams API page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) to help me decide between a `Collection` and a `Stream`:

> However, [the Streams API] has many benefits. First, the Streams API makes use of several 
>   techniques such as laziness and short-circuiting to optimize your data 
>   processing queries.

Both a `Stream` and a `Collection` can be used to apply a computation on every single element of a dataset before storing it. However, I've found `Streams` useful if my pipeline includes several distinct filter/sort/map operations for each data element, as the Stream API can optimize these calculations behind the scenes and has parallelization support built in as well.

I agree that readability can be affected both positively and negatively by using a `Stream` - you're correct that some `Stream` examples are completely unreadable, and I don't think that readability should be the key decision point for using a `Stream` over something else.

If you're truly optimizing for performance on a large dataset, consider using a toolset that's purpose-built for massive datasets instead.

Comment: I may have put too much focus in the formulation of my question on performance, as performance (i.e. time performance as most would understanding) is only part of my motivation. More precisely I am interested in how adequate it is to use `Stream`. That said, if I understand your answer correctly, it seems to address the point. Let me paraphrase what I understood: "`Stream` usage is not related to the size of the dataset but more to the complexity of the operation you want to apply to the said dataset." Am I correct in my interpretation?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct to me @Eldros. If you can easily separate out distinct steps to apply to each dataset member, a `Stream` seems like a solid bet since that API can combine steps whenever possible.

Comment: But the scope of your input, i.e. do you want to do a precise strike and cast your net wide? Citing the [`Stream` API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html): "_Collections are primarily concerned with the efficient management of, and access to, their elements. By contrast, streams do not provide a means to directly access or manipulate their elements, and are instead concerned with declaratively describing their source and the computational operations which will be performed in aggregate on that source._" Shouldn't it also be a factor?

Comment: I think what you're asking makes sense, but notice that every `Stream` operation always ends with a `Collector` to bring all of the processed `Stream` elements back into a `Collection`. In my mind, the most significant factor that would make me choose a `Stream` vs a `Collection` is how well my necessary data manipulations can be translated into distinct `Stream` API operations that could then be parallelized by the underlying API. If whatever I need to do isn't neatly describable by the `Stream` API methods, a `Collection` makes more sense - `Stream` operations end up as `Collections` anyway.