# adding an ArrayList to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Conceptually what is going on here?

I have an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> myArray = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
```

then I add something to it like this

```
myArray.add(new myArray(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two arrays in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Comment: `myArray` is an  `ArrayList`

Comment: @JoelWitteveen that is not correct. The question was about the way in which an array list contains arrays

Comment: you should use something like `myArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3))`

Comment: `new myArray(1, 2, 3)` is not correct, how could you use `new` keyword to instantiate a not existing class `myArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an array
>
> ```
> ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
> ```

No, you don't have an array. Arrays are declared using brackes `[]`, like this:

```
int[] myArray;
```

You have an object of [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class. This object will use an array internally to store the data and dynamically change the array for a newer one when needs to assign more values.

> then I add something to it like this
>
> ```
> myArray.add(new myArray(1, 2, 3));
> ```

Conceptually, this is wrong and won't even compile. If you want to add more than one value in your array, you should use `ArrayList#addAll` method, that receives another collection. Then, you have two ways to pass a `Collection` in one statement:

1. Create a list using `Arrays#asList`:

   ```
   myArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
   ```
2. You can use double brace initialization:

   ```
   myArray.addAll(new ArrayList() {{
           add(1);
           add(2);
           add(3);
       }});
   ```

---

You should take into account that you should specify the generic for your `ArrayList` instead of using raw data:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myArray.addAll(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(1);
        add(2);
        add(3);
    }});
```

More info:

- [Java Tutorial. Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)
- [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1005073/1065197)

---

Note that if you have an `ArrayList` that is tied to a custom class, let's say `ArrayList<SomeClass> myArrayList`, then the compiler prevents you to add elements to the list that doesn't pass the IS-A test (noted by `instanceof` operator), so this code:

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> myArrayList = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
myArrayList..addAll(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(1);
        add(2);
        add(3);
    }});
```

Won't be able to compile since `Integer` is not a `SomeClass`. Similar with this piece of code:

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> myArrayList = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
myArray.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

But due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) you can trick the compiler by using raw types. For example:

```
public void addData(ArrayList yourArrayList, Object anyData) {
    yourArrayList.add(anyData);
}
```

Then in your code, you call this method:

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); //allows Strings only
myArrayList.add("Hello world");
//myArrayList.add(0); //this won't compile because trying to add an Integer
addData(myArrayList, 0); //this will compile for using raw ArrayList and sending an Integer
System.out.println(myArrayList);
```

It will print:

```
[Hello world, 0]
```

Comment: "**Conceptually what is going on here?**"

Comment: if you know the size of the added arraylist, it would be nice the define the size of the arraylist : `new ArrayList(size)`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He seems to be asking what an arraylist is / how it works. Nothing else.

Comment: @JordanD to begin with, that code doesn't compile nor even work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza , he did not ask to make it work. He wants to know what it means to have an arraylist

Comment: @downvoters, i cannot understand why downvote this answer when the question is buggy and unclear.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, that is a much better answer. You may even link him to the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza great, I would say this question is pretty much answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray.add(new myArray(1, 2, 3));
```

This is not correct and don't compile, cause `myArray` is not a type, it's just a reference, you need something of type integer or if you want to add another list, then use `addAll`.

You could use something like this.

```
List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>(); // specify with generics type parameter
//do some things and then
myArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)); // use this helper method to add a list to another list
```

Or if you want to only create and populate it, just use

```
List<Integer> myArray = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: The user asked: "**Conceptually what is going on here?**"

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're trying to do, say you have this.

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```

and you wanted to add an array to it, you're basically going to call

```
myArray.add(((Integer[]) new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }));
```

Which will add the array [0, 1, 2] to the next index in the ArrayList.

For exmaple, the following code

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
myArray.add(((Integer[]) new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }));
myArray.add(((Integer[]) new int[] { 1, 0, 2 }));
myArray.add(((Integer[]) new int[] { 3, 2, 1 }));
```

Would create the following results:

```
myArray index 0 = [0, 1, 2]
myArray index 1 = [1, 0, 2]
myArray index 2 = [3, 2, 1]
```

Is this your question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have an array, you have an ArrayList. An ArrayList is a resizable implementation of the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. This means, among other things, that you don't have to define a length like you would with an array.

I don't think the code you have provided will actually compile because when you go:

```
myArray.add(new myArray(1, 2, 3));
```

you haven't provided a type. You should go something like:

```
myArray.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
```

Using [asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) will give almost the equivalent of assigning "default" values to an array. The array equivalent would look something like this:

```
Integer[] intArray =  new Integer[] {1,2,3};
```

You should also parameterize your `ArrayList`(s), this basically means you are saying what that ArrayList can hold. For instance:

```
ArrayList<Integer>
```

Can hold Integers.

The reason you must use a wrapper class (`Integer` & not `int`) is because Collections in Java don't permit you to store primitive types such as `int` or `double`.

You can have a Collection holding another Collection. In this case you could go:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    myArrayList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    myArrayList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(9, 12, 24)));
    for (ArrayList<Integer> index : myArrayList) {
        System.out.println(index);
    }
```

Here you have an ArrayList holding two other ArrayLists. This results in the printing of:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[9, 12, 24]
```