# Print properties of an Object

Tags: java

I cannot get the properties of a certain card in this code it always prints `null` and I don't know why. I'm from Php-HTML world and I'm a newbie on JAVA.

This is the from `Opportunity.java`

```
package opportunity;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import opportunity.Card.CardType;

public class Opportunity {
    /*Player 1 */
    public int p1_money = 10000;
    public int p1_card_d = 40;
    public int p1_card_h = 0;
    /*Player 2 */
    public int p2_money = 10000;
    public int p2_card_d = 40;
    public int p2_card_h = 0;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        System.out.print("***************Opportunity***************\n");

        final Card card1 = new Card(Card.CardType.EVENT, "Get Tax Returns").
        setProperty("cost", "0.00").
        setProperty("Effect", "Effect: Earn money equal to the\n"
                + "maximum income each of your\n"
                + "properties can give you,\n"
                + "depending on their level.");
        final Card card2 = new Card(Card.CardType.EVENT, "BIR Hunting Begins").
        setProperty("cost", "0.00").
        setProperty("Effect", "Effect: An opponent loses\n"
                + "money equal to 50% of the\n"
                + "maximum income each of\n"
                + "their properties can give him or her,\n"
                + "depending on the level of the\n"
                + "property.");
        final Card card3 = new Card(Card.CardType.EVENT, "Restore Balance").
        setProperty("cost", "10000.00").
        setProperty("Effect", "Effect: The total income of all\n"
                + "the players becomes equal to\n"
                + "the income of the player\n"
                + "with the lowest income.");

        final List<Card> deck = Stream.of(CardType.values()).
        flatMap(type -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).mapToObj(num -> new Card(type, "CardName" + num))).
        collect(toList());
        Collections.shuffle(deck);

        System.out.println(deck.get(0).getProperty("Effect"));


    }

}
```

And This is the codes from `Card.java`

```
package opportunity;

import java.util.*;


public class Card {
    public enum CardType {
        EVENT,
        PROPERTY,
        ASSET;
    }
    private final CardType cardType;
    private final String cardName;
    private final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    Card(final CardType cardType, final String cardName) {
        this.cardType = cardType;
        this.cardName = cardName;
    }

    public Card setProperty(final String name, final String value) {
        properties.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    public String getProperty(final String name) {
        return properties.get(name);
    }
}
```

It always returns this:

```
run:
***************Opportunity***************
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

even though I put an index on `get()`

Comment: Please describe your code in brief and tell what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're adding the cards to the deck. I'm not sure what your lambda function is trying to do, but it'd be easier to just `add` to an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on @Luiggi Mendoza's answer, you are not adding your Card objects to the `deck` list.

Replace

```
final List<Card> deck = Stream.of(CardType.values()).
flatMap(type -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).mapToObj(num -> new Card(type, "CardName" + num))).
collect(toList());
```

With

```
final List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
deck.add(card1);
deck.add(card2);
deck.add(card3);
```

Instead of adding new `Cards` to the list, add the objects you have already created - and have properties set.

Edit: to address your comment

```
final List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    deck.add(card1);
    deck.add(card2);
    deck.add(card3);
}
```

This will add four copies of each of your three cards to the list.

Comment: But the one that you want me to replace create 4 copies of the card.  so there must be a total of 12 cards, 4 of the `card1`, 4 of the `card2`, 4 of the `card3`.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
final List<Card> deck = Stream.of(CardType.values()).
    flatMap(type -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).mapToObj(num -> new Card(type, "CardName" + num))).
    collect(toList());
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
```

You fill `List<Card> deck` with new `Card`s, you don't add any of the other `cardX` variables. Thus, when retrieving this `"Effect"` property, you get `null` because the `Card`s in `deck` don't have the `"Effect"` property set before.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of the previous folk is totally right. You are not adding the created cards to the list.

Try replacing your code

```
final List<Card> deck = Stream.of(CardType.values()).
    flatMap(type -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).mapToObj(num -> new Card(type, "CardName" + num))).
    collect(toList());
```

for standard list creation and adding. For instance (and updated for 4 cards):

```
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    deck.add(card1);
    deck.add(card2);
    deck.add(card3);
}
```

If you want to minimise the number of lines of code, there are ways to initialise a new list with content. Try this post [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line).

Anyway, always try to code the simplest solution, even more when starting with a new language.

Comment: The code that you want me to replace creates 12 cards to make a deck. 4 card1, 4 card2, 4 card3.