# How to create a linked list in java?

Tags: java, string, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I would like to write a linked list like this:

```
"a" -> "b" -> "c" -> "d"
```

This is what I've tried so far but it's obviously wrong. I was wondering how to express this correctly in java?

```
LinkedList<String> s = new LinkedList<>();
s = {"a"->"b"->"c"->"d"};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how the pointers in the list look internally, to actually [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E)) it to the list you need to do this:

```
List<String> s = new LinkedList<>(); 

s.add("a"); 
s.add("b");
s.add("c");
s.add("d");
```

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: Misclick, I mean to upvote it. Sorry about that :P.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005083/2197700).

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
```

If you really want it on one line:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d"));
```

Though that does have a performance overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
    linkedList.add("a");
    linkedList.add("b");
    linkedList.add("c");
    linkedList.add("d");
```