# What is wrong with new ArrayList<String>().add("something")

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the problem of initiating an `ArrayList` by:

```
new ArrayList<String>().add("something");
```

And why we should use the following to initiate an `ArrayList`:

```
new ArrayList<String>() {{ 
    add("something");
}};
```

Comment: What's wrong with this `new ArrayList<String>.add('something')`? It won't compile ...

Comment: Thanks down voter, it seems that stackoverflow become for proficient developer only.

Comment: Maybe you would get better result with a better question? For example with code snippets which are compilable? But this is just a guess, I don't know why they voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *should* not use [double brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/1743880)! You *can* but it doesn't mean you *should*.

To get back to your question

```
new ArrayList<String>().add("something");
```

The problem with this is that this actually returns a `boolean`: the result of the `add` method. The list you just instantiated is lost and will be garbage collected.

What you should do instead is keep a reference to the list and use it to add the value.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("something");

// or simpler
list = Arrays.asList("something"); // warning fixed-size list
```

Comment: But if I write "return new ArrayList<String>().add("Something")" in  a method it's returning type is List<String>, it would causes a compilation error, since I'm return a boolean, But that is did not happened

Comment: @hbak I didn't understand your comment. `new ArrayList<String>().add("Something")` returns a boolean value, not a List. Try to write `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>().add("Something")` and you will see that there is a compilation error.

Comment: @hbak why would you have a method that instantiates a new list but returns a boolean?

Comment: If I have the following declaration for a method ` List<String> splitMultiValues` .. and the return statement for this method is  `List<String> list = (List<String>) (x== null ? new ArrayList<String>().add(cellValue) 
    :  y);
  return list;`

Then what will happen?

Comment: @hbak `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

Comment: @Andreas, actually it returns null (I don't know why)

Comment: To get a variable-size list, you can combine the two shown ways: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));`

Comment: @hbak Well that does `y` equal to?

Comment: it's ArrayList<String>

Comment: @hbak If `x` is not null and `y` is null, then you get null.

Comment: @Andreas and Tunaki. Thanks guys, I will debug the code to see what is really going on. I've done with stupid questions :)

Comment: @hbak Debugging the code sounds like a great idea indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is wrong. You can get it working if you follow this answer:

[Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("something");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Array<String>().add("Something");
```

is not the only way to do this. You could use something like:

```
Arrays.asList("Something","Something Else");
```

This returns a `List<String>` though.