# Adding data of different type and from different class in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

So i have recently started learning java and currently studying Array List.

Suppose that i have two classes A and B. In class A i have two attributes which are string type 'name' and int type 'age'.

In class B i have an array list and what i want to do is add the value of name and age in the array list.

How can i do that and also how can i add different type of data in one Array list ?
Following is the code in the two classes that i have written but compiler gives error.

```
public class A {

    public String name;
    public int age;

    public input()
    {
        name = "ALI";
        age = 20;
    }

}  

public class B{

    A obj = new A();
    ArrayList aa = new ArrayList(); //error here

     aa.add(obj.name); //error here

}
```

Comment: your code example is not compilant... please fix that

Comment: do you want to add in the list `String` and `A` types?

Comment: i don't understand. What do you want me to do with the code ?

Comment: I would expect the error is actually on your line `A obj = new input()`, since `input` is  a method in class `A`. Change to be `A obj = new A(); obj.input();`, and then you can add to the array list. Of course, that assume you want to add the name to the array and not the object. You should add the type to the ArrayList to make your intent clearer. Also, please add the compiler errors in the future.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko i want to add the attributes in class A in the array list. Also i want to know how to add different type of data in arraylist

Comment: @KevinO actually instead of input its A ... its a mistake ...

Comment: @Yousaf, if there is an error in the posted code, then people cannot truly assist you. However, if the line was `A obj = new A()`, then the NPE you were receiving in the aa.add(obj.name) is because name was never set (you need the call to .input() to set it).

Comment: @KevinO i have edited my post

Comment: Did you import ArrayList in your file?

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias yes i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet was not much clear. I assume that your are trying  to do this.

ClassB

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    class ClassB {

        public String name;
        public int age;

        public ClassB() {
            name = "ALI";
            age = 53;
        }

    }
```

ClassA

```
public class ClassA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassB obj = new ClassB();
        ArrayList aa = new ArrayList();

        aa.add(obj.age); // int
        aa.add(obj.name); // string

        aa.add(15.2); // float
    }

}
```

If you notice that float is also added in arraylist. As you want to add other data type. As long as you have not specified any specific generic data type to any of collection classes. You can add any data type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object of the **class A** and then add it to the list defined in the class B, this is done using the field values of A or even better using *getters*

## Example:

```
public class Tester {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    public Tester()
    {
        name = "ALI";
        age = 20;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
         Tester t = new Tester();
         myList.add("Name: "+t.name+"; Age: "+t.age);
         System.out.println(myList);
         
    }
}
```

the class Tester is the same as the **class A** and the snippet in the main method can be moved to another **class B**

Comment: i have tried this but it generates error that array list does not take parameters.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to initialize an object of class A.

```
A obj=new A();
```

Then you can assign the values to the A type object by calling input() method.

```
obj.input();
```

Then you should give the type of elements in the ArrayList in B.Since you want to put Strings in **aa** ArrayList, the type should be specified as **ArrayList`<String>`**.

```
ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>(); //error here
aa.add(obj.name);
```

Note: If you want to add different types of objects in one ArrayList, you will have to study the concept of polymorphism since you are new to Java. The easiest, but not recommended way is to use an ArrayList of type **Object** which is the parent class of all Java classes.

```
ArrayList<Object> list=new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Now you can add anything to this list.

```
String a="example";
list.add(a);
int b=10;
list.add(b);
```

and so on....

Comment: ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<>(); this line generates error that array list does not take parameters

Comment: ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
aa.add(obj.name); Did you try this part?

Comment: the error says that the ArrayList does not take parameters. If i remove <String> from the line where ArrayList is declared, the error is fixed.

Comment: I see. But that is impossible. By the way, if it works for you, carry on with it. Also refer the following question about initilizing array list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line

Comment: But i can't add the 'name' from class A in the array list. It gives error.  This is what i am doing.  ArrayList aa = new ArrayList();
                 aa.add(ob.name);

Comment: That is incorrect. You should do as specified in the question I added before. You should give a type to the ArrayList