# How to add elements to Java static ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have class like this:

```
public class Info{ 
public static String id;
public static ArrayList<String> poruceno;
}
```

And now I am trying to populate arraylist 'poruceno' from another class:

```
Info info;
info.id="bla bla bla" //works perfectly
info.poruceno.add("some string"); //Returns null pointer exception :(
```

I need to add elements from many other classes to this ArrayList 'poruceno' from class Info. Please help :)

Comment: You need to initialize your ArrayList. `poruceno = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Initialize the Arraylist as `poruceno=new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line

Comment: **Check this out :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first at all, do init the list at the point of defining it:

```
public class Info{ 
    public static String id;
    public static List<String> poruceno= new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

then use it from other classes

```
Info.poruceno.add("Hello");
Info.poruceno.add("World");
```

Comment: Ouch... Tnx mate! :)