# Initiate List<WebElement> in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Its a similar question to this one: [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

I am trying to initialize a List Variable.

```
List<WebElement> variable = new List<WebElement>() {{
...
}};
```

This is not Working. No idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is an interface.
You need a class to instantiate a list - like ArrayList.