# Can you assign to multiple variables at once from values in an array in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

In Perl, I can say:

```
my @list = ( 1, 2, 3 );
my ( $a, $b, $c ) = @list;
```

In Java, as far as I can tell, I need to do this:

```
List<Integer> list = { 1, 2, 3 };
int a = list.get(0);
int b = list.get(1);
int c = list.get(2);
```

Does there exist some kind of syntactic sugar that will let me assign all three variables in a single line of code, like Perl?

Comment: Java doesn't have anything like tuple unpacking. But you can do that in one statement, though (not particularly helpful): `int a = list.get(0), b = list.get(1), c = list.get(2);`

Comment: What ernest_k said is about as good as it gets with Java, I think, unless you wrote a method that emulates this functionality.

Comment: You can create own functional interface 'populate' for example, pass to there result and array, populate somehow, as you wish)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

Comment: Good to know that it wasn't just my own inability to find it, that it really doesn't exist.  Thanks.

Comment: @ernest_k well not exactly what I wanted, but much cleaner than adding a line per variable. Good tip.

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave a comment, but want to say that what @ernest_k posted assigning multiple variables on one line in the comment above is a good catch. My code is much cleaner now, thanks!

> int a = list.get(0), b = list.get(1), c = list.get(2);

Also works with simple arrays and final keyword if anyone is wondering:

> final String a = array[0], b = array[1], c = array[2];