# When did add() method add object in collection

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, static

I have two questions. Firstly, consider the below code.

```
public class Test{
    private static final List<String> var = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("A");
        add("B");
        System.out.println("INNER : " + var);
    }};

    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("OUTER : " + var);
    }   
}
```

When I run this code it gives me below output

```
INNER : null
OUTER : [A, B]
```

Can any one elaborate why `INNER` is null and execution flow at a time when exactly "A" & "B" added to `collection`?

Secondly, I made some changes in above code and modified to below one (just put add method within first bracket)

```
public class Test{
    private static final List<String> var = new ArrayList<String>() {
        public boolean add(String e) { 
            add("A");
            add("B");
            System.out.println("INNER : " + var); return true; 
        };
    };

    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("OUTER : "+var);
    }   
}
```

After running above code i got below result

```
OUTER : []
```

After viewing this I'm totally clueless here about what is going on. Where did `INNER` go? Why is it not printing? Is it not called?

Comment: this btw is a big anti-pattern

Comment: You need to use `"INNER " + this` to print out the current state of the ArrayList, `var` is not assigned at this time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Because the initializer block of the anonymous class off `ArrayList` is executed *before* the instance reference of the anonymous class is assigned to `var`.
2. The code is not executed because you never call the `add(String e)` method. If you did, it would result in a `StackOverflowError`, since `add("A")` is a recursive call now.

Comment: if i call add() from main method how does it becomes recursive call(i check it as you mentioned it gives StackOverflowError)

Comment: @RBS The first statement inside `add(String e)` is `add("A")`, which is a call to itself, so it executes `add("A")`, which is a call to itself, so it executes `add("A")`, which is a call to itself, so it executes `add("A")`, which is a call to itself, so it executes `add("A")`, which is a call to itself, so it executes `add("A")`, and **StackOverflowError**.

Answer (score 5):

1. The object you created has not been assigned to `var` in the initialization procedure, try this:

   ```
   private static final List<String> var = new ArrayList<String>() {{
       add("A");
       add("B");
       System.out.println("THIS : " + this); // THIS : [A, B]
       System.out.println("INNER : " + var); // INNER : null
   }};
   ```
2. You just override `add` method of `ArrayList`, it's nerver been called. It  works like:

   ```
   static class CustomList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

       @Override
       public boolean add(String e) {
           add("A");
           add("B");
           System.out.println("INNER : " + var);
           return true;
       }
   }

   private static final List<String> var = new CustomList<>();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In your code snippet 1, you are using the *double brace initialization* to add items to the array list. It is basically an anonymous inner class with an instance initializer. Since you print `var` before the object is constructed it is `null`.

In your second snippet, you are creating an anonymous class of ArrayList providing an implementation of the `add` method. But no one calls the `add` method on the ArrayList object.

**EDIT:** Good point made by [Andreas@](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52689687/4405757) - Even if you call the add method, it will result in an infinite recursive call resulting in a `StackOverflowError`.

Reference:

[Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

Answer (score 1):

In the first code you print the variable before that its constructor has returned as you add the elements and print the list inside the instance initializer. 
So it can only print `null`.

In the second code you override `add()` to add hardcoded elements but `add()` is never invoked on the created instance. So `add()` doesn't print anything and nothing is added in the List instance either.

To add elements in a List you generally want to invoke `add()` on the List reference such as :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("element A");
list.add("element B");
```

You don't create an anonymous class for such a requirement.

If you want to use a simpler syntax you can still do :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("element A", "element B"));
```