# Java: How to differentiate when to declare an Object instance of itself or its parent?

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java. I am confused if the followings are correct or not.

The first condition is understood and is used frequently. What are the usages of others? When and how can I utilize them?

```
/* 1) */ Car car = new Car();
/* 2) */ Car car = new Vehicle();
/* 3) */ Vehicle car = new Car();
/* 4) */ Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
```

Perhaps you could include examples in your answer.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: How are `Car` and `Vehicle` related? Does one extend the other?

Comment: If I understand correctly (Car is a subclass of Vehicle), `Car car = new Vehicle();` will not compile because a Vehicle is not a Car, but a Car is a Vehicle.

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials: Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: Vehicle mVehicle = (Vehicle) new Car();     // see always prefix variables with something "m".  I've casted Car to Vehicle.  This should work because Cars are always Vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should just declare variables by the most general interface that you are going to use (e.g. `Iterable`, `Collection`, or `List`), and initialize them with the specific implementation (e.g. `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` or `Arrays.asList()`).

Otherwise you're limiting your code to that specific type, and it'll be harder to change when you want to.

For example, if you're passing an `ArrayList` to a `void method(...)`:

```
// Iterable if you just need iteration, for (String s : strings):
void method(Iterable<String> strings) { 
    for (String s : strings) { ... } 
}

// Collection if you also need .size(), .isEmpty(), or .stream():
void method(Collection<String> strings) {
    if (!strings.isEmpty()) { strings.stream()... }
}

// List if you also need .get(index):
void method(List<String> strings) {
    strings.get(...)
}

// Don't declare a specific list implementation
// unless you're sure you need it:
void method(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    ??? // You don't want to limit yourself to just ArrayList
}
```

---

Another example would be always declaring variable an `InputStream` even though it is usually a `FileInputStream` or a `BufferedInputStream`, because one day soon you or somebody else will want to use some other kind of `InputStream`.

Comment: I copied this from another answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676539/233014

Answer (score -1):

In many cases the superclass (or interface) describes a general Object but the subclasses differ in implementation to make the code either more efficient or more accessible.

A good example is the interface `List`. It has two main subclasses `AbstractList` and `AbstractSequentialList`. These provide implementations of most methods in `List`, but leave the actual memory management up to their subclasses.

When I create a `List` object, it's usually because I want a length-changing array and not because of `ArrayList`'s exact implementation (Although it does specify a few more useful methods which you can't access in `List`).
This means I just say

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();
```

because I want a list but have to also specify the implementation that's most efficient for my cause.

When it comes to your `Vehicle` and `Car` classes, I say it depends on what you want to achieve. In this case specifying your `Car` object as follows is probably the most sensical:

```
Car car = new Car();
```

because you are asking for a car specifically and aren't just using `Car` as a certain implementation of `Vehicle`.

In conclusion:

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClassSuperclass();
```

is most useful and readable when `SomeClass` is just an implementation of `SomeClassSuperclass`.

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
```

is most useful and readable when `SomeClass` is supposed to be a different type of `SomeClassSuperclass`, but still has it's own features that make it a `SomeClass` rather than a `SomeClassSuperclass` (Think of a car in real life, you don't point to a car and say "Look, An awesome vehicle!" or "Look, I got a new vehicle!", as those phrases don't really give you much information about what you are talking about)