# Java 11+ "generic array creation" error (using BlueJ)

Tags: java, arrays, string, calendar, bluej

I'm new to Java and I'm using the current version of BlueJ to do my programming. When trying to initialize a string array containing all the days of the week I am greeted to the error message "generic array creation" I am curious on how to fix this as all the results I've found online have been quite old and out of date. The code is for a clock that can also track the day of the week. The code I have as follows:

`daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<String>[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};`

I will be more than happy to update this post with any other information that may be needed to provide help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to pre-define values in an ArrayList.

Comment: Use `List.of("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")`. It's just a List, not an ArrayList,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

Comment: `List<String> daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"));`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I plan on having it tick through the array with the rest of the clock. Will that still work with a list?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch He uses Java 11, teach him the right thing to do: `List.of`. It's unlikely that the number of days in a week change anytime soon.

Comment: @Makk Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I'm still using Java 8, but I think the "right thing to do" would be: `List<java.time.DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(java.time.DayOfWeek.values()));`  (or `List.of(java.time.DayOfWeek.values())` since, as you say, Java 11+). [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) is a nice `enum`. Seems a shame to not use it.

Comment: Using `java.time` is not a bad idea. There is always a better way to write some code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Because `DayOfWeek` is an `enum`, I'd personally opt for an `EnumSet` (`EnumSet.allOf(DayOfWeek.class);`), but that's a valid solution nonetheless.

Comment: @JacobG. Then it would be easier: `EnumSet.allOf(DayOfWeek.class)`, but this is a `Set`, not a `List`.

Comment: Honestly, don't encourage people to use `Arrays.asList` except in super-specialist cases. A `List` that allows element mutation but not structural mutation? Eurgh. That sort of confusion we can all do without. `List.of` unless there is a very good reason not to. (Some of the streams API is worse.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Java 13, generic array creation is still forbidden. The reason has to do with the fact arrays know their component type at runtime but generics suffer from what's known as [type-erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). That said, your question has the following example:

```
daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<String>[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
```

The above is trying to create an `ArrayList<String>[]`; in other words, an array of array-lists. This is most likely not what you actually want to do. Despite the name `ArrayList`, the class isn't directly involved in the creation of arrays—the name just means the list is *backed* by an array. Given that your data is simply the name of each day of the week, what you probably want is a `String[]` or `List<String>`:

```
// array
String[] daysOfWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

// list
List<String> daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"));
```

Note that if you're not using Java 11+ you can replace the use [`List#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) with [`Arrays#asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)). If you are using Java 11+ then consider using the result of `List#of` directly, rather than copying the result into a modifiable `ArrayList` (assuming you don't plan on modifying the list).

You may also want to consider using the [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum instead of a `String` to represent each day of the week. An enum is more type-safe, less prone to error, and allows easy interaction with any other `java.time` classes you may use.

```
List<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek = List.of(DayOfWeek.values());
```

---

You should always default to using a `List` (or some other collection) before using an array. If you absolutely must use an array, you can work around the "generic array creation" error with the following:

```
// unbounded T
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] array = (T[]) new Object[size];

// or if, for instance, T is upper-bounded by CharSequence
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] array = (T[]) new CharSequence[size];

// or if the component type is itself generic
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Comparator<String>[] array = (Comparator<String>[]) new Comparator[size];
```

However, all of the above is simply a compile-time trick. Each of the arrays will still allow any object that's an instance of the raw component type to be stored without throwing an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime. In other words, the first array will still accept any `Object`, the second array will still accept any `CharSequence`, and the third array will still accept any `Comparator<?>`. This is why an "unchecked cast" warning is emitted for each of the above; that is, if there were no `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation present.