# How to Create and Initialize (in Java) a List<String[]> in the same statement? (Editors please NOTE: this *not* the same as just a List<String>)

Tags: java, arraylist, new-operator

Is it possible to combine the creation of a `List` of `String[]` with the initialization of the first entry in the `List`?

```java
final List<String[]> rolesCsv = new ArrayList<String[]>();
rolesCsv.add(new String[] {"Role Name","Description"});
```

In other words, can I combine the above two lines into a single one that both creates and initializes the `List`?

The `List<String[]>` does need to be mutable for later adding to the `List`, yes.

**IMPORTANT NOTE for EDITORS: Creating and initializing this definition is far different than solutions for simply creating and initializing `List<String>`- BEFORE you automatically link this question to the common answers for the latter, please stop! The problem is different and requires a different solution.**

Comment: Does it need to be an ArrayList or can it be any kind of list? Does it need to be mutable?

Comment: @user16320675 yes... thank you ! You should post this as the answer, since all other answers posted elsewhere only deal with atomic types inside a list (such as List<String>)...  thanks for your excellent answer.

Comment: @stdunbar points to the right question, and probably [you need this answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676539/10621296), the one with the header "If you specifically need a java.util.ArrayList"

Comment: In general, you don't want to mix arrays and `List`s. Why not a `List<List<String>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was given in the comments (above) by **@user16320675** , and this works well. It handles both the creation of the outer List and the internal array of strings. Other answers pointing to a simple Array asList are for simple strings, which is not the question that was asked.

to create a mutable list

```java
final List<String[]> rolesCsv =
     new ArrayList<String[]>Collections.singletonList(new String[]{"Role Name","Description"}));
```

Otherwise (despite the array, its element, will not be immutable)

```java
final List<String[]> rolesCsv =
      Collections.singletonList(new String[]{"Role Name","Description"})
```

Answer (score -1):

`List<String> sameline = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");`

This is the way to **Create** and **initialize** Java List in the same line.

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked..