# Generating random numbers and sorting them out in Java

Tags: java, sorting, random, linked-list

My goal is to generate random number from 0 to 100 and add them into a linkedlist object and then sort the elements.

This is my code so far. I'm running into problems when I want to display the sorted elements.

The error I get:  Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

Can someone throw some light into this problem? Thank You

```
package com.LinkedLists;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class InsertRandomElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a random number object from 0 to 100.
        // Create an array object.
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] random = new int[100];

        // Insert random numbers into the array
        for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            random[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
        }

        // Printing out the unsorted array
        for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(random[i]);
        }

        List<int[]> randomList = Arrays.asList(random);

        // Call the method in here.
        sortElements(randomList);

    }

    // Sort the elements
    private static void sortElements(Collection<int[]> values) {

        Set<int[]> set = new HashSet<int[]>(values);

        for (int[] is : set) {
            System.out.printf("Sorted Elements: %d ", values);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    // Calculate Sum of the elements

    // Calculate floating point average of the elements.

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace

Comment: Are you sure you want a list of arrays? `List<int[]> randomList`, Seems you would net a list of Integers `List<Integer> randomList`.

Comment: Also, do you have to use a *linked* list?

Comment: I used List<Integer> randomList = Arrays.asList(random); initially but it won't let me use the Arrays.asList.

Comment: @Appsheriff take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248763/arrays-aslist-of-an-array I think my answer is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You need a `List<Integer>` and not a `List<int[]>`. Converting from a primitive array into a list of Integers is not a one-call operation, you'll actuall have to iterate over the primitive array and add to the list one by one. I don't recommend this, especially since there is no reason to use the array in the first place. For reference, you need this:

```
final List<Integer> randomList = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i : random) randomList.add(i);
```

When you change that, this will work:

```
System.out.printf("Sorted Elements: %s ", values);
```

However, it would be much simpler to sort the array itself using `Arrays.sort(myArray)` and then print using

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

On the other hand, if you used a `List<Integer>` right from the start, it would look like this:

```
final Random rnd = new Random();
final List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) values.add(rnd.nextInt());
Collections.sort(values);
System.out.println("Sorted Elements: " + values);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its getting confused because **`int[]` is an object but `int` is not so it assumes `int[]` as one element of the `List`, and hence returning `List<int[]>` not `List<Integer>` or `List<int>(this is not possible and is causing the issue)`.

Please change your random to `Integer[]` as below, it should work fine.

```
    Integer [] random = new Integer[100];
    List<Integer> randomList = Arrays.asList(random);
```

To sort the list: Use `Collections#sort`

```
    Collections.sort(randomList);
```

**Please remember**, the method signature is: `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)` which determines the type of List to be returned based on the argument type being passed.

**Please Note:**  Even when you define `random` as `new Integer[100];`, still you can leave this kind statements as is: `random[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;`. This works fine as `int` is promoted to `Integer` in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think it would be easier to pass the `random` array directly to a `sortElements(int[] values)` method and *then* convert the array to a list.

In other words, you would call `sortElements(random);` and then `List<Integer> randomList = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(random));` to get a linked list.

Answer (score -1):

Using your code try:

```
for (int[] is : set) {
   System.out.printf("Sorted Elements: %d ", is[0]);
}
```

but you still need to sort it, as mentioned in previous post