# Checking if an array has a certain character, why is my code not working?

Tags: java, arrays, search, contains

Hello here is some code to check for a valid character, although the code is not working. Even if 'operand' is a valid character it will never print yes, and return false. No matter what even if the character is valid it just doesn't recognize it and always goes to the else statement. Please help!

```
public static boolean checkValidOperands(char operand) {

    char[] validOperators = {'+', '-', '*', '/', 'q'};
    List<char[]> validOp = Arrays.asList(validOperators);
    if (validOp.contains(operand))  {
        System.out.println("Yes");
        return false;
    }  else {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid operand");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a `List` of `char[]`'s, not a `List` of `char`'s.

Comment: how can I fix this code so it works?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248763/arrays-aslist-of-an-array Edit: Or @Reimeus answer

Comment: Are you sure the declaration for validOp shouldn't be a List<Char> rather than a List<Char[]>? You're not looking for a list of character *arrays*, but just characters...

Comment: Yup looks like this is the problem, I tried List<Char> but <Char> is not recognized...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
List<Character> validOp = Arrays.asList('+', '-', '*', '/', 'q');
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are creating a list of characters is wrong.

In your current code the list that you made is actually a list of character arrays, instead of characters.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    char ch = '+';
    System.out.println(checkValidOperands(ch));

    }

    public static boolean checkValidOperands(char operand) {

        Character[] validOperators = {'+', '-', '*', '/', 'q'};
        List<Character> validOp = Arrays.asList(validOperators);
        if (validOp.contains(operand))  {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            return false;
        }  else {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid operand");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Also for future, do not use `List<char>`, `List<int>` etc.. as you cannot use a primitive type for generic in Java. Use their corresponding Object counter parts instead. Refer to this question for more information [Why can Java Collections not directly store Primitives types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/why-can-java-collections-not-directly-store-primitives-types)

Answer (score 0):

A string is a better data structure for a set of characters. For example,

```
String validOperators = "+-*/q";

if (validOperators.indexOf(operand) != -1)  {
    System.out.println("Yes");
    return false;
}
```