# Output or return in Java without using the letter e or digit 5

Tags: java, escaping

For this [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/46909/32700) on PCG.SE, one is required to write a function/program that returns/outputs the first N primes.

However, the characters with prime code points are not allowed in the program.

Two of these characters are `5` and `e`. The code points of either letter contain a `5`. Because of this, `\u{codepoint}` won't work for those two letters.

Using escapes, I can remove all prime characters from the code except for the `e` in `return`.

I could use `System.out` or `FileDescriptor.out` but both contain the letter `e`.

Is there any way to return or output without using an `e` or `5`?

For reference here is my code with characters escaped:

```
int[]b(int b\u0029{
    int c,d,f[]\u003d{}\u003b
    for(f\u003dj\u0061v\u0061.util.Arr\u0061ys.copy\u004ff(f,b\u0029\u003bb-->0\u003b\u0029
        for(d\u003d0,c\u003d2\u003bf[b]<1\u003bf[b]\u003dd<1?c:f[b],d\u003d0,c\u002b\u002b\u0029
            for(int h:f\u0029
                d\u003dh>0&&c\u002fh*h\u003d\u003dc?1:d\u003b
    return f;
}
```

Without characters escaped:

```
int[]b(int b){
    int c,d,f[]={};
    for(f=java.util.Arrays.copyOf(f,b);b-->0;)
        for(d=0,c=2;f[b]<1;f[b]=d<1?c:f[b],d=0,c++)
            for(int h:f)
                d=h>0&&c/h*h==c?1:d;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @piotrek The question is clearly stated: "Is there any way to return or output without using an e or 5?"

Comment: You could fill an array passed as a parameter, i.e. an output parameter.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20169645#20169645

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've found a way to output the prime numbers without using `System.out`, `FileDescriptor.out`, or `return`.  My method uses no "prime" characters.

This was very tricky, because `e` is all over the place in Java package names, class names, and method names.  Also, `S` must be prohibited, because it's number `83` in Unicode, and `83` is prime.  Its Unicode escape `\u0053` contains a `5` whose Unicode character `53` is also prime.  Here are all the characters we can't use a Unicode escape for under these rules:

- `%` (37  is prime, `\u0025` has a `5`)
- `5` (53  is prime, `\u0035` has a `5`)
- `S` (83  is prime, `\u0053` has a `5`)
- `Y` (89  is prime, `\u0059` has a `5`)
- `e` (101 is prime, `\u0065` has a `5`)

This eliminated:

- Any methods such as `toString`, `fromString`, `parseInt`, `valueOf`, and `values`.
- `java.beans`, `java.net`, `java.lang.reflect` packages
- `Class.forName`
- Use of the `new` operator.
- Logging frameworks that usually use a `Logger` class that contains `e`.

Here are characters for which we can use Unicode escapes:

- `)` (41  is prime, `\u0029` is allowed)
- `+` (43  is prime, `\u002b` is allowed)
- `/` (47  is prime, `\u002f` is allowed)
- `;` (59  is prime, `\u003b` is allowed)
- `=` (61  is prime, `\u003d` is allowed)
- `C` (67  is prime, `\u0043` is allowed)
- `G` (71  is prime, `\u0047` is allowed)
- `I` (73  is prime, `\u0049` is allowed)
- `O` (79  is prime, `\u004f` is allowed)
- `a` (97  is prime, `\u0061` is allowed)
- `k` (107 is prime, `\u006b` is allowed)
- `q` (113 is prime, `\u0071` is allowed)

Attempting to generate an exception whose message contains the desired output is the only way to fulfill the requirement in Java.  We cannot use a checked exception, because just about all checked exceptions I could find use an `e` in their name, and in every superclass up through `Throwable`.  I would be required to use a `throws` clause that included an exception name that contained an `e`.  I couldn't `extend` any classes, because `extends` contains `e`s.

That leaves unchecked exceptions.  The most likely use would be an `IllegalArgumentException` that is created not by this code directly, but by a call to something built-in that throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

- `Enum`s would have helped, except `valueOf` contains an `e`.
- `javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance` has an `e`; it throws a checked exception anyway.
- `javax.naming.ldap.Rdn.unescapeValue("\\b" + stringFormOfOutput)` outputted the list via an exception, but the method has an `e`.
- `java.util.UUID.fromString` outputted the list via an exception, but the method has a `S`.

[This method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html#unmarshal-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) throws a [`DataBindingException` which is unchecked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DataBindingException.html).

- `javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(stringFormOfOutput, Long.class)` outputted the list via a `DataBindingException`, without an `e`.

Now all we have to do is convert the `int[]` to a `String`.  String conversion by concatenating the array to `""` doesn't work, because [arrays, as objects in Java, don't override `toString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array).  `Arrays.toString` is out because of the `S`.

We can use `Arrays.asList` to get a `List` out of the data.  But [`Arrays.asList(f)` gives a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248763/arrays-aslist-of-an-array), compounding the problem.  Changing the type of `f` to `Integer[]` won't work, that has an `e`.  Changing the type of `f` to `Long[]` works.

The conversion of the array to a `String` is as follows.

```
Long c,d,f[]...
""+Arrays.asList(f)
```

In place of the `return` statement, make the method `void`, and call `unmarshal`.  The use of `Long` means a few other adjustments are necessary, such as using `long` literals and `fill`ing the array with zeros instead of the default `null`s.

```
void b(int b){
    Long c,d,f[]={};
    for(f=java.util.Arrays.copyOf(f,b),Arrays.fill(f,0L);b-->0;)
        for(d=0L,c=2L;f[b]<1;f[b]=d<1?c:f[b],d=0L,c++)
            for(long h:f)
                d=h>0&&c/h*h==c?1:d;
    javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(""+Arrays.asList(f),Long.class);
}
```

Escaping the "prime" characters:

```
void b(int b\u0029{
    Lon\u0067 c,d,f[]\u003d{}\u003b
    for(f\u003dj\u0061v\u0061.util.Arr\u0061ys.copy\u004ff(f,b\u0029,Arr\u0061ys.fill(f,0L\u0029\u003bb-->0\u003b\u0029
        for(d\u003d0L,c\u003d2L\u003bf[b]<1\u003bf[b]\u003dd<1?c:f[b],d\u003d0L,c\u002b\u002b\u0029
            for(lon\u0067 h:f\u0029
                d\u003dh>0&&c\u002fh*h\u003d\u003dc?1:d\u003b
    j\u0061v\u0061x.x\u006dl.bind.JAXB.un\u006d\u0061rsh\u0061l(""\u002bArr\u0061ys.\u0061sList(f\u0029, Lon\u0067.cl\u0061ss\u0029\u003b
}
```

This is ugly code, and it probably won't win any code-golfing contests, but it is the only way I can think of in Java to fulfill the requirements.

Calling this `b` method with `10` as an argument yields the following output, with `[29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2]` being the first 10 primes:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.DataBindingException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\src\misc\[29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2] (The system cannot find the file specified)]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:208)
    at Main.b(Main.java:34)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:90)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\src\misc\[29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2] (The system cannot find the file specified)]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:205)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\src\misc\[29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2] (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:799)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    ... 10 more
```

But what about `public static void main(String[] args)`?  There is a seemingly unavoidable `S`.  Make `b` `static` and call `b` with a static initializer, to eliminate `main` and its `String[]` requirement.

```
st\u0061tic
{
   b(10\u0029\u003b
}

st\u0061tic void b(int b\u0029{
// ...
```

The output now contains an `ExceptionInInitializerError`, but the rest of the output is intact; the `DataBindingException` is chained.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:87)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.DataBindingException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\src\misc\[29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2] (The system cannot find the file specified)]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:208)
...
```

Comment: Very nice, I'm not sure if I should be impressed or appalled :D

Comment: This is amazing! If I had more reputation I would give you a bounty.

Comment: However, you forgot to escape the `+` operator.

Comment: Good catch!  I've escaped the `+` operator now.

Comment: +1. This had to be pretty difficult for you to figure out, and your explanation of how you did this is fascinating. (BTW, how much time did it take to do this?)