# trouble initialize List<Object[]> Using Arrays.asList

Tags: java, list, generics

When I initialize List, I am able to do this:

```
List<Object[]> foo = new ArrayList<>();
foo.add(new Object[]{816, "foo", 2.6});
```

But when I want to simplify it using `Arrays.asList`:

```
List<Object[]> bar = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286});
```

It cannot compile with error:

```
incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: java.lang.Object[]
lower bounds: java.lang.Object
```

Why it cannot do the type inference right and how to fix this?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248763/arrays-aslist-of-an-array

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, never mix generics and arrays. (You are allowed to disregard this rule once you understand why it's a good rule of thumb in the first place.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember that `...` is just syntactic sugar for an array parameter. You can call a method with a variadic parameter `foo(Object...)` either using

```
foo("hello", 1);
```

or

```
foo(new Object[]{"hello", 1});
```

since the compiler constructs the second form anyway.

Because the receiver type isn't considered when the compiler infers types, it looks at `Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286})` and thinks that you mean to create a list of `Object`, not a singleton list of `Object[]`.

The easiest way with your existing syntax is just to add an explicit type parameter:

```
List<Object[]> bar = Arrays.<Object[]>asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286});
```

Adding the `<Object[]>` tells the compiler what T should be.

Or, if you don't need the list to be mutable:

```
List<Object[]> bar = Collections.singletonList(new Object[]{"bar", 286});
```

Answer (score 13):

When you pass an array of reference types to `Arrays.asList` you get a `List` of that reference type.

Therefore `Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286})` returns a `List<Object>`, not a `List<Object[]>`.

Answer (score 7):

If your list only has one element in it, `Collections.singletonList(new Object[] {...})` is a better choice, as it avoids varargs and makes the behavior more obvious at the call site.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `Arrays.asList` is a varargs method which technically receives an array containing the arguments and due to compatibility with pre-generics code still accepts an array instead of an argument list. When passing a single array, the call is ambiguous and will be handled like a pre-varargs method invocation.

The problem disappears when you have more than one argument:

```
List<Object[]> bar = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286}, new Object[]{"baz", 123});
```

If you have only one argument you can aid the compiler by inserting an explicit list element type:

```
List<Object[]> bar = Arrays.<Object[]>asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286});
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
List<Object[]> bar = Collections.singletonList(new Object[]{"bar", 286});
```

to create an immutable list of size one. Note that this differs from `Arrays.asList`, as the latter returns a list of fixed size but still mutable via `set`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) signature:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

The return type is `List<T>`. Now you should ask yourself what is `T`?

`T` is `Object`, so the return type will be `List<Object>`, and not `List<Object[]>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your call:

```
Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286});
```

creates a list out of the `Object[]`. So the data is convertet into a new `List<Object>`.

So `Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286}).get(0);` will return "bar".

In this call:

```
List<Object[]> foo = new ArrayList<>();
foo.add(new Object[]{816, "foo", 2.6});
```

you are creating a `List<Object[]>` (2Dimensional) and add one element after it: `foo.add(..);`.
Therefore you are adding one element consisting of an `Object[]`.
if you now call `foo.get(0);` you will get a `Object[]` consisting of:
816, "foo", 2.6

I think you wanted to do:

```
Object[] oa = new Object[]{""};
Object[] ob = new Object[]{""};
List<Object[]> list = Arrays.asList(oa, ob);
```

If you have questions, feel free to ask me :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `List<Object[]> bar = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"bar", 286});` you actually have a two dimensional Array and you cand resolve that problem by doing `List<Object[]> bar = Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{new Object[]{"bar","asd",123}});`