# java.lang.ClassCastException:[I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int l1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());int count=0;
        String l2=br.readLine();
        String[] a=l2.split(" ");int[] no=new int[l1];
        for (int i=0;i<l1;i++) {
            no[i]=Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
        }
        List list=Arrays.asList(no);
        Set<Integer> set=new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list);
        ***for (int integer : set) {***
        count=Math.max(count, Collections.frequency(list, integer));
        }
    }
}
```

I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at Solution.main(Solution.java:23)` at the highlighted part of the code. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays.asList() of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248763/arrays-aslist-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to initialize a set from an array of primitive integers. When you do this

```
List list=Arrays.asList(no);
```

since `List` is untyped, you construct a list of integer arrays; this is definitely not what you are looking for, because you need `List<Integer>`.

Fortunately, this is very easy to fix: change declaration of `no` to

```
Integer[] no=new Integer[l1];
```

and construct `list` as follows:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(no);
```

Everything else should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<Integer> set=new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list);` produce unchecked warnings. This masks that the correct generic type of `list` is `List<int[]>`, so `set` contains not `Integers` as intended, but arrays of `int`s. That's what is reported by `ClassCastException`: `int[]` (referred as `[I`) cannot be cast to `Integer`.

The simplest way to fix this code is to declare `no` as `Integer[]`, not `int[]`. In this case, `Arrays.asList` will return correctly-typed `List<Integer>`.