# android async task

Tags: android

I have a app I'm making with an AsyncTask. The result of the task needs to be assigned to a variable in the base app class. I currently have:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(int[][]... end) {
        MainVar=end[0];
    }
```

but this doesn't transfer the data. I'm guessing I'm going about this wrong, but I wasn't sure how to do it reading the docs, so how should this be done?

Comment: Post your entire AsyncTask code, please.

Comment: Here's a simplified form:
http://pastebin.ca/2016721

Answer (score 1):

It's generally right what you tried. You're given the result of the type int[][] in onPostExecute(). But don't use primitive types. AsyncTask Extensions are generic and need three types: `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`
which may be Void or anything else (but no primitive data type). Hope that helps!

Comment: so should I have the data type be "Integer[][]" instead?

Comment: Yes, you could use that. But I wonder how you implemented your AsyncTask with int[][] , as the java compiler already should have complained because generics don't accept primitive types...

Comment: The pastebin I posted above shows that AsyncTask code.
http://pastebin.ca/2016721
It does sometimes say something about xlint, maybe that's what xlint would tell me.

Comment: Ok. I made out an older post here about generics:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types

Comment: After converting the int to Integer, I still have the data not being transferred. Here is an updated pastebin of the other var in case it helps. http://pastebin.ca/2016858

Comment: I looked into it, but I didn't see any Integer Objects..? The int's definitely won't work ;) Did you instantiate and execute your AsyncTask? I saw you used it as an inner class. It would be useful to have a look at the whole code.