# Does <String> do anything?

Tags: java, generics, primitive-types

`List<String>` works with or without but `List<int>` doesn't. I've always wondered about this.

Comment: with or without what? It's probably because String is a class and int is a native type.

Comment: with or without what? ooops, 3 seconds too late ^^

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Comment: b/c you can't cast java.lang.Object to int

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't Generics support primitive types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists (and other collections) can keep only objects, not primitive types. So you can use `List<Integer>` but not `List<int>`. `String` is also an object — that's why it works.

And regarding the difference between `List` and `List<String>`: the difference exists only during the compilation. In runtime all both lists are identical.

Comment: Thanks for that. SO it just casts it as a String object type?

Comment: @CoolBeans: that doesn't make sense. If you are using Generics, you don't need casts. That's the whole point. The compiler will insert the casts and *guarantee* by type checking that there are no ClassCastExceptions. And the only way you *can get* a ClassCastException is by *doing* a cast.

Comment: @EJP: You are right. My comment was backwards. I meant to say you should not do List some = new ArrayList<>(); without specifying a type (generic or not). I will delete my comment. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use primitive types (`byte`, `short`, `int`, [etc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).). You must use the wrapper type which, in this case, is `Integer`

```
List<Integer>
```

This type of casting is called generics, and you can start learning more about them [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html).

Answer (score 3):

`List<int>` doesn't work because Java generics doesn't deal with primitive types - only Objects (or subclasses thereof, like `Integer`).  You aren't required to specify the type parameter when using a generic class, but the compiler will issue a warning and you'll be required to take care of all the type casting (including dealing with potential `ClassCastExceptions`) and such yourself.