# Why do the Integer.valueOf(...) comparisons in this example return different values?

Tags: java, autoboxing

From the answer to a [question about primitive types and autoboxing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199359/why-do-people-still-use-primitive-types-in-java/5199425#5199425):

> for biziclop:
>
> class biziclop {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     System.out.println(new Integer(5) == new Integer(5));
>     System.out.println(new Integer(500) == new Integer(500));
>
>     System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(5) == Integer.valueOf(5));
>     System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(500) == Integer.valueOf(500));
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> Results in:
>
> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>java biziclop
> false
> false
> true
> false
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>
> ```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer.valueof caches objects for values around zero as required by the Java Language Specification.

Inspired by [ilya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238287/why-do-the-integer-valueof-comparisons-in-this-example-return-different-valu/5238429#5238429) see [the latest, actual source for Integer.valueOf()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/c53711f82bfb/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) in the upcoming JDK7, lines 638-643.

Answer (score 3):

See Integer.valueOf realization: http://docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html (850s line)

Comment: Note:  This is Apache Harmony source, not Oracle Java source.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the equal method not the == operator. == test if two objects are equal but you create different objects with same value and need the `equal()` method to compare the object's values.

Update:
Reason for different behavior of `Integer.valouOf(5)` and `Integer.valouOf(500)` is indeed that Integer implementation uses a static valueOfCache of size -128..127. 
As of Java 7 this is configurable with the command-line argument `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size>`

Comment: I didn't intend to compare the values but was looking for an explanation as to why the results of the two comparisons are different while they seem to be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Integer.valueOf caches values, specifically -128 to 127.