# What is the difference between being shallowly and deeply equal? How is this applied to caching?

Tags: java, caching, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Found the following in my notes, but I am unable to make sense of it:

> Primitive type wrapper classes implement caching for a limited number
>   of values.
>   This guarantees that a limited number of deeply equal wrapper objects are
>   also shallowly equal:
>   If `o1.equals( o2 )` then `o1 == o2`.
>   For example, `new Integer( 0 ) == new Integer( 0 )`.
>   In general this does not always work.
>   For example, new Integer( 666 ) == new Integer( 666 )
>   may not hold.
>   The reason for caching is that it saves memory.
>   In general caching works for “small” primitive values.

I don't understand what is meant by this, or what the difference is between a deep (.equals()) and shallow(==) equals. I know in practice, .equals must be used to objects and == for Integral values, but the actual reasoning for this alludes me.

I assume by the names that shallow maybe just checks that both the values are of the same type and name, which deep checks that both variables point to the same object? I don't see how the caching would come into play here though, or why it would be useful.

Comment: Well, your notes are completely wrong.  `new Integer( 0 ) == new Integer( 0 )` will **never, ever, *ever*** be true, nor will `new Integer( 666 ) == new Integer( 666 )`.  I suggest you ask your professor for clarification on what he meant, because if he expects this on an exam, he knows little about Java.

Answer (score 9):

When you do `==` you are comparing the references for equality. This means you're saying "is the address in memory the same for both Objects?"

When you do `.equals()` you are comparing the Objects themselves for equality. This means you're saying "do these two Objects consider themselves equal?"

The example that was given was poor. **The only caching done for these numbers that's mandated by the JLS is the `.valueOf()` method.** The constructor is not cached.

Furthermore, the JLS only specifies the **minimum** you must cache [-128:127]. JVM implementations may cache more if they so choose. This means `Integer.valueOf(500) == Integer.valueOf(500)` may be `false` on some machines, but `true` on others.

```
class biziclop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Integer(5) == new Integer(5));
        System.out.println(new Integer(500) == new Integer(500));

        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(5) == Integer.valueOf(5));
        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(500) == Integer.valueOf(500));
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>java biziclop
false
false
true
false

C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>
```

See a more detailed answer here (the comments are a gem!): [Why do people still use primitive types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199359/why-do-people-still-use-primitive-types-in-java/5199425#5199425)

Comment: Hi,
how are the outputs of 
 System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(5) == Integer.valueOf(5));
 System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(500) == Integer.valueOf(500));


different??

Comment: That's the entire point of the answer: `5` is small enough that the JVM caches it, while `500` isn't. Although it could be, so on some rare machines it could be the same (both true) but on most machines `5` will be cahced and thus return the same Integer object while `500` won't be so `valueOf` will create `new Integer`s.

Answer (score 9):

Well, actually shallow/deep dissection is different from ==/equal dissection:

1. == compares for object identity, that is you checking whether
   operands are the same in fact
   (two references to the same area of memory),
   whereas `equals` compares for object
   equivalence, that is "logical" value
   of two, possibly not identical
   objects, is the same. If for two
   objects

   ```
   a == b
   ```

   then it's true that

   ```
   a.equals(b) // if a != null
   ```

   , but opposite isn't true in all
   cases.
2. shallow/deep distinction makes sense
   only for `equals` comparison.
   Shallow means that you compare only
   immediate contents of two objects to
   find whether they "equal" in your
   sense, whereas deep means that you
   compare contents of your objects
   recursively until all you need to
   compare is primitive fields.   If
   you define `equals` method of your
   objects as sequence of calls to
   `equals` on instance fields of these
   objects, you use deep comparison. If
   you define `equals` using `==`
   operator to compare compound types,
   such as Strings, then you use shallow comparison -- and that's incorrect in Java.

Morale of all of this is that you must never use `==` to compare two compound objects, unless you consider them equal only if they are the same.

Comment: What you say is true, but it looks as though the lecturer was using "shallow" to mean reference identity, and "deep" to mean equivalence. The logic is certainly sound.

Answer (score 2):

What you call "shallow equal" is *identity*: two references (i.e. objects) are identical if they are the very same instances. If you know what pointers are in other languages, you can compare identity to pointer equality.

What you call "deep equal" is *equality*: two objects `a` and `b` are equal if `a.equals(b)` returns `true` (and hopefully vice versa). The correctness of equality strongly depends on the way the `equals` method is implemented. See the Javadoc of the `Object` class for more details.

Answer (score 2):

First off: `new Integer(0) == new Integer(0)` will **never** evaluate to `true`, as `new` **always** creates a new object, sidestepping any autoboxing-caching mechanism that might exist.

What you probably heard about was autoboxing (i.e. automatic conversion of primitive values to their respective wrapper classes when necessary). Autoboxing uses a mechanism that's also accessible using the wrapper classes `valueOf()` methods. In other words: auto-boxing an `int` to an `Integer` works pretty much the same as calling `Integer.valueOf(int)`.

`Integer.valueOf(0) == Integer.valueOf(0)` **will** evaluate to `true`, because common values (i.e. values with a low absolute value) are cached. You'll get the **same** `Integer` object when you call `valueOf(0)` twice in a row. This is not necessarily true with higher values (such as 666 in your example).

Answer (score 1):

equals() tests whether two objects are essentially the same, but it can return true for two distinct objects; i.e., two different paper clips are "equals". "==" for reference types tests whether two references refer to the same object -- i.e., a paper clip is == only to itself. == tests *identity*, which `equals` tests *equivalence*.

You could have two distinct Integer objects with a 0 in them (they are `equals()`); caching means saving objects and reusing them when possible.