# How to test an array of objects with JUnit

Tags: java, arrays, junit

Trying to check a method which adds a module object to an array works correctly. How do I write a JUnit test which tests to see if an object has indeed been added to the array?

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Test
public void testAddModule() {
    Student chris = new Student("Chris", "1");
    Module csc8001 = new Module("CSC8001", "Programming and data structures", 5, 5, 0, 7);
    Module csc8002 = new Module("CSC8002", "Programming II", 5, 5, 0, 7);   
    chris.addModule(csc8001);
    chris.addModule(csc8002);


    Module [] expectedResult = {csc8001,csc8002};
    ModuleRecord[] resultArray = Student.moduleRecords;

    Assert.assertArrayEquals( expectedResult, resultArray );

}
```

The problem I have is the array is just storing references to the objects, how do I test to see if the array is storing the correct information?

Comment: Your test is already right. Or do you want to test that the Modules in Student.moduleRecords don't change when you change csc8001?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track: `assertArrayEquals` should work. The concept you're looking for is the difference between [shallow equals ("`==`") and deep equals ("`.equals`")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5703609/1426891), which is related to the difference between [reference equality ("`==`") and object equality ("`.equals`")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7520432/1426891).

If two arrays have the same length, and contain the exact same primitive values and references, it's easy to say that they're equal: `[0, 1]` equals `[0, 1]` even if the arrays themselves are different objects, and the same happens for `[csc8001, csc8002]` and `[csc8001, csc8002]`. This is known as "shallow" equality, and it's very very fast to compute.

If you're actually looking to compare the objects using their `equals` methods, you need "deep" equality. This checks the proper number of entries, and checks that `x[n].equals(y[n])` for all `n`. This may take longer, because Java can't just compare the references; it actually calls a method on the objects. This is only of value to you if you override `equals`, though; if your Module doesn't override `equals` it uses Object's built-in `equals` method, which acts the same way `==` does.

In any case, it's not very clear in the documentation, but [`Assert.assertArrayEquals`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L281) calls [`Assert.internalArrayEquals`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L530), which basically does a [deep comparison using `.equals`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/ExactComparisonCriteria.java#L8).

That leaves you with three options:

- Keep using `assertArrayEquals`. That's what it's there for, and because equal references imply equal objects, it's the right thing to do.
- Keep using `assertArrayEquals` but also write a `Module.equals` method to prove the data itself is identical. Remember, this is only an issue if you want to prove that two different instances behave as if they were equal based on their data, and you probably don't have to worry about that right now.
- Break out what you're testing for, as Jason mentioned, which confirms that the data is correct without having you write an `equals` method:

  ```
  assertEquals(2, resultArray.length);
  Module addedModule = resultArray[1];
  assertEquals("CSC8002", addedModule.code); /* ... */
  ```

If you ever do try overriding `equals`, be careful: You'll need to uphold some rules and you'll also need to override `hashCode`. [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/1426891)

Answer (score 0):

The brute force method is to check that the array has the expected number of entries, then each object stored in the array has the expected attribute values.