# == for case class and "non-case" class in Scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I am studying Scala and ran into the following puzzle.

I can define the following case classes:

```
abstract class Expr
case class Number(n: Int) extends Expr
```

When I create two instances from the class `Number` and compare them

```
val x1 = Number(1)
val x2 = Number(1)
x1 == x2
```

I have the following result:

> x1: Number = Number(1)
>
> x2: Number = Number(1)
>
> res0: Boolean = true

So `x1` and `x2` are the same.

However, if I drop the `case` modifier in the `Number` class definition, i.e.

```
abstract class Expr
class Number(n: Int) extends Expr
```

and then compare two instances from the `Number` class in the same way

```
val x1 = new Number(1)
val x2 = new Number(1)
x1 == x2
```

I have the following output:

> x1: Number = Number@1175e2db
>
> x2: Number = Number@61064425
>
> res0: Boolean = false

It says that this time `x1` and `x2` are different.

Could you tell me why is this? What difference does `case` make in terms of comparing two instances?

Thanks,
Pan

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly created `val x2 = Number(2)` which should have been `val x2 = Number(1)`. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you define a case class in Scala, the compiler generates an `equals` method which checks for deep equality (i.e., the contents of the class).

From: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107

> For every case class the Scala compiler generates equals method which implements structural equality and a toString method.

When you drop the `case` keyword, you generate regular classes, and doing an `==` on them checks for reference (shallow) equality. Since you're comparing two unique instances of the class, they fail reference equality even though their contents are the same.

For difference between shallow and deep equality, see:
[What is the difference between being shallowly and deeply equal? How is this applied to caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703609/what-is-the-difference-between-being-shallowly-and-deeply-equal-how-is-this-app)

Comment: For precision's sake, calling `==` does not force a reference equality check, it will actually call the `equals` method that you can override to do anything you want. Reference equality is just the default implementation for normal classes, forcing a reference equality check could be done via the `eq` method. This behavior of `==` is different than in Java for example.

Comment: Usually words "shallow" and "deep" are used in different sense than in this answer. Normal classes does not override equals(), and the default implementation is "referential" equality, that is, compare the references of objects themselves. Case classes compare their fields for equality, but they delegate the comparison to fields' equals() methods, which, if defined the same way, lead to deep equality, but if not, lead to shallow equality (only 1 level deep). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy