# Troubleshooting: comparing keys of two maps (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, maps, key

So I'm trying to compare the keys of two maps. The code below is syntactically valid; however, it returns false even though the keys of the two maps are similar. What could be the problem here?

```
const sc = new Map ();
sc.set ("item1",1)
sc.set ("item2",1)
sc.set ("item3",2)
sc.set ("item4",1) //ounce per serving //

const ing = new Map();
ing.set ("item1",1)
ing.set ("item2",1)
ing.set ("item3",2)
ing.set ("item4",1) //ounce per serving //

function compareMaps (map1,map2) {
if (ing.keys() == sc.keys() && (ing.size == sc.size)) {
    return "true"
} 
    return "false"

} 

compareMaps(ing, sc)
```

Comment: `img.keys() == sc.keys()` this is always going to be false, as they are two different objects (albeit with the same values). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703609/what-is-the-difference-between-being-shallowly-and-deeply-equal-how-is-this-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948335/how-can-i-check-if-two-map-objects-are-equal#:~:text=First%20check%20the%20.,its%20values%20to%20the%20other.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that as a problem. Because (ing.size == sc.size) works fine. Do you have any suggestions on how I can compare the keys aside from the map size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check [`Map#size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) of both maps and take the key in an array and check against with [`Map#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has).

```js
const sc = new Map();
sc.set("item1", 1)
sc.set("item2", 1)
sc.set("item3", 2)
sc.set("item4", 1) //ounce per serving //

const ing = new Map();
ing.set("item1", 1)
ing.set("item2", 1)
ing.set("item3", 2)
ing.set("item4", 1) //ounce per serving //

function compareMaps(map1, map2) {
    return map1.size === map2.size && [...ing.keys()].every(Map.prototype.has, map2);
}

console.log(compareMaps(ing, sc));
```

Comment: [...ing.keys()] What is the ellipsis for?

Comment: @inforoverload [read up on "spread" syntax here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Your `ing.keys() == sc.keys()` comparison is flawed.

The [`Map.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) method returns an *Iterator* to an object containing all keys of the Map (sorted in insertion order). Since `ing.keys()` and `sc.keys()` are returning separate objects, even if they may have identical keys, a comparison of the two values will *always return `false`*.

Answer (score 0):

The `keys()` method is returning separate array objects. Although all of the elements within them are the same, they are two separate objects, and are therefore not equal.

What you need is a deep equal, which is something you can write yourself or bring in a dependency for, like [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual). They have a lovely `isEqual()` function which does a deep comparison for you.