# Java - Byte array uses 4 times as much ram as set

Tags: java, arrays, ram

I played around a little bit with Java's arrays and I realized that a 1GB big byte array needs 4GBs RAM.
That's my code **(make sure you have at least 4GB unused RAM or your PC might freeze)**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Byte[] array = new Byte[1073741823]; // Equals 1GB

    System.out.println("Done");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println("Completely done");
}
```

That's my machine:
MacBook Pro (64bit; running OS X 10.9 on it)
Java: Java SE 6 (1.6.0_65-b14-462) and Java SE 7 (1.7.0_45).
RAM: 16
Used RAM: about 10GB

When I start this application, it uses 4GB instead of 1. I used these arguments to start that program: `-Xmx8g -d64`.

Comment: Max memory is set at 8g, why are you surprised it reserved 4?

Comment: try printing `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` and see what you get

Comment: Well, if I set it to 4GB it uses exactly 4. If I set it below, it'll give me a out of memory exception. So, why is it me giving me a out of memory exception then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because Byte is an object, which requires enough memory to hold an object reference. You want the lower-case "byte" for the primitive type.

Comment: Wouldn't 4gb be too little for a 1GB `Byte` array though?

Comment: Here's another good SO reference for the general objects vs primitive type question (beware auto-boxing pitfalls!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199359/why-do-people-still-use-primitive-types-in-java

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: 4gb is too little for a 1gb capital-B Byte array, but it should be plenty of room for a 1gb byte array.

Comment: @ScottDudley so why does it only take 4gb in this case?

Comment: @benjamin-gruenbaum You mean: why does the 1 million capital-B Byte array only require 4gb instead of 8gb? In theory, a million object references on a 64-bit JVM should require 8 bytes * one million = 8gb. But later versions of the Oracle JVM use [Compressed Oops](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) by default, which reduces memory consumption significantly. If you turn off Compressed Oops by rerunning the program with `-XX:-UseCompressedOops`, it will suck up the 8gb you expected.

Comment: Most JVMs use 32-bit references even on 64-bit JVMs.  Each reference is typically 4 bytes. https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops