# Which is more intensive - Modulo vs String<->Int conversion?

Tags: java, string, int, type-conversion, modulo

Consider the following 2 (sort of) pseudo code blocks (my question is specific to Java though) -

```
//BLOCK 1 (using modulo)
for(int i=0,i<N,i++){ //N is in the order of millions
   int temp1 = a%10;
   int temp2 = a/10;
   // more code adding temp1 & temp2, etc.
   }

//BLOCK 2 (using int <-> char conversions)
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) { //N is in the order of millions
    if(a>9){
       String t1 = String.valueOf(a);
       Integer temp1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.CharAt(0));
       Integer temp2 = Integer.parserInt(t2.CharAt(1));
    }
    // more code adding temp1 & temp2, etc.
}
```

My question is - keeping everything else the same, compare the 2 ways of obtaining temp1 & temp2 in the 2 code blocks above.
Which one is more intensive? I think it should be the modulo but I am not sure. Because string<->int<->char conversions are not CPU intensive I believe. I could be entirely wrong and hence I am posting this question.

(PS. Most of you may have guessed that I am trying to get the 1st and 2nd digits of a 2-digit number and you're correct.)

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(char)`? I think not; but if you have a single character (e.g. a hex special case) then a lookup or switch is likely faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that converting an integer into a string actually calls the modulo (or division) function quite a bit anyway, so I suspect the string one will be slower. That's on top of the fact that you're doing work with classes rather than primitive types.

But you should *measure, not guess!* Without measurement, optimisation is a hit-and-miss operation.

Try each of your proposed solutions in a ten-million-iteration loop and time tem. That's a good start.

Comment: @user2864740, that code you link to is `parseInt`, turning string into integer. Turning integer into string (the opposite operation) will use modulo (or division), a not inexpensive operation. In OpenJDK, that's done by `String.valueOf(int)` which calls `Integer.toString(int)` which calls `Integer.getChars()` which _does_ use division (and modulo emulated with bit-shifting and subtraction) in a loop.

Comment: Ah, missed the task reversal.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : modulo is clearly faster because you are working with a int.

Long answer : Block 1 uses primitives and block 2 uses classes which adds overhead.  It is not very significant for something this simple but it will still requires more cpu cycles.  You can have a look at this nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199359/why-do-people-still-use-primitive-types-in-java) about primitives in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know is test it in your environment.

Comment: Should be a comment; not enough relevant information provided.