# Increment a number in steps e.g. 2, 4, 6, 8

Tags: java

I have a StepCounter class which extends Counter. Counter has an increment method which adds 1 to the counter. I need override this method so that increment method in the StepCounter class will increment the counter by the value of "step" e.g. if step=2 then the increment would add 2 to the counter instead of 1. Somehow I can't make it work. This is the coding I've done:

```
public class StepCounter extends Counter {

    //fields
    private int step;

    //constructors
    public StepCounter() {
        super();
        step = 2;
    }

    public StepCounter(int count, int step) {
        super(count);
        this.step = step;
    }

    //methods
    public void setStep(int step) {
        this.step = step;
    }

    public int getStep() {
        return step;
    }

    @Override
    public void increment() {
        super.getCount() += step;
    }   
}
```

I've already tried various styles like

> super.getCount() += getStep();

etc...

BTW getCount() method returns count value from Counter class.

Comment: What do you want to do with the incremented value? It is never assigned anywhere?!

Comment: @DaDaDom, the increment method should increment the count value from the Counter class. I've used super.getCount() because it returns count value. I want to create an ArrayList of type StepCounter and add some data into it. I then want to create a for loop which will print 10 results one next to another showing how the counter works.

Answer (score 3):

You get the value, but you dont set it.
Try it this way:

```
setCount(getCount() + step);
```

Also the `super` keyword isn't needed in this case, if your inheriting class doesn't override `getCount()`, it's much more readable without it.

Comment: @Lazio you should really start accepting answers that helped you, so that others see, that those questions are answered.

Answer (score 0):

the `getCount()` method is inherited from counter so you should go this way

```
 @Override
    public void increment() {
        Integer tmp = this.getCount() += step;
        setCount(tmp);
    }
```

Also in the no-arguments constructor you should initialize the step variable properly.

```
public StepCounter() {
    super();
    this.step = 2;
}
```

Comment: `Also in the no-arguments constructor you should initialize the step variable properly.` There is no need to use `this` here.

Comment: As i suspect `count` to be primitve, this summons unnecessay autoboxing.

Comment: I avoid primitives when dealing with mathematical operations anywhere for reasons of my own and prefer autoboxing with exception handling.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199359/why-do-people-still-use-primitive-types-in-java#5199425