# How to convert double to object?

Tags: java, file, type-conversion, jspinner

I am writing part of my program which read data from a txt file.

I have problem when I want to set value of JSpinner by setValue(object).

My data is double so I need to convert it to object, but how?

```
LoadData open = new LoadData();
data.setFz(open.giveAwayData());
spinner_1.setValue(data.getFz()); // Fz is double
```

Comment: I've just tried it and I can use a double as the argument, with no casts nor conversions ;)

Comment: I restared eclips and everything is ok now. Weird bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not as weird a bug as you think.  Eclipse has a tendency to lose its mind every now and then, and you have to restart.  It happens far too often.  You just have to get used to it (like I do), or switch to IntelliJ (which I hear is a little more stable, but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 3):

Try casting it to Double (with capital):

```
spinner_1.setValue((Double) data.getFz());
```

Comment: If this is an answer, it shouldn't end with a question mark.  :)  Also, showing the code would be really helpful.  I think this is the right answer, but you just need a little more to make it a good answer.

Comment: Ideally this would be a comment but I can't comment yet so deal with it. But I'll edit it as to your suggestions.

Comment: I dont understand what mean with capital. Give some code, please.

Comment: @Xalion "capital" means upper-case.  Java distinguishes between `double`, which is a primitive type and not an object, and `Double`, which is an object.  `Double` begins with an upper-case (capital) D.  Often Java will automatically convert between the two (boxing and unboxing).

Comment: spinner_1.setValue((Object) data.getFz());

it should look like that, but it doesnt work.

Comment: @Xalion Does your IDE specifically say that it's the wrong parameter type? If so, your method doesn't _actually_ have a parameter typed `Object` at all. Otherwise, you must be mistaking which bit of your code is erroneous.

Comment: @bcsb1001 The parameter type is `Object`; I looked up `JSpinner` to confirm this.  Apparently the IDE had lost its mind.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Double.valueOf(data.getFz())`. An explanation of the differences between primitives and boxed primitives can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199359/why-do-people-still-use-primitive-types-in-java); basically, primitives have better performance but the boxed classes are there for when you need an `Object`. A common example is with [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), which cannot be primitives.

**However**, a `double` can be passed to something requiring a `Double` or one of its superclasses. This is because of [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). Yes, I like links a lot.

Comment: it doesnt work... i need OBJECT, not double.

it is setValue(object)

Comment: Like I said, autoboxing should solve that problem for you. Also, `Double` is a subclass of `Object`. But you can always use `Object obj = data.getFz();` (autoboxing lets that work).

Comment: Never use `new Double`.  Always use [Double.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-double-) instead.

Comment: @VGR, yeah, forgot that was in `Double` too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for example the `Double` constructor to convert `double` primitive type to a `Double object`.

```
Double dObj = new Double(d);
```

or you can cast it to Double like this:

```
spinner_1.setValue((Double)data.getFz());
```

Comment: Why do you need a cast? Or explicit Double creation? Autoboxing should take care of it right...

Comment: @Codebender:- Indeed! `new Double(data.getFz())` is fine.

Comment: it is setValue(object). I need object inside... how to set number... it should be easy.

Comment: @Xalion:- You can try: `setValue(((Number)object).doubleValue())`