# How to convert entire double[] array into an Object

Tags: java, arrays

I have a function in a jar file which accepts two parameters:

1. An Object array which mentions the type and number of output
2. An Object array which contains input to the function.

The input I need to pass consists of 7 objects. I have to send two `double[]` arrays and rest all 5 are double values.

I would like to know how to convert `double[]` into an `Object`.

Please help me with this.

If i want to convert a single double value to an object of Double, I can use the following code.

```
public class JavadoubleToDoubleExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 10.56;

    /*
    Use Double constructor to convert double primitive type to a Double object.
    */ 

    Double dObj = new Double(d);
    System.out.println(dObj);

  }
}
```

Output:

> 10.56

But what if the `d={1.0,8.9,4.0,7.9}`.

How can I convert the array into an object of `Double`?

Comment: Post your code to get context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert double to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289779/how-to-convert-double-to-object)

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: I am using Java

Comment: Hugo de Heer I want to convert entire array into an object not only a single double value

Comment: Use a for loop?

Comment: Arrays are already objects in Java. Do you mean "How to write a wrapper class for double array" ?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are already Objects in Java. If you want to convert an array of primitive double into an array of Objects:

```
double[] nums = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7};        
Object[] objs = new Object[nums.length];

for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
    objs[i] = new Double(nums[i]);
```

Comment: `convert the array into a single array` What do you mean?