# Is a Java double array faster than an object instance

Tags: java

Is it more efficient to be doing this:

```
double[] a = new double[5];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
}
```

rather than this:

```
public class DataStore {
    public double a, b, c, d, e;

    public DataStore(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
    }
}
...
new DataStore(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Is there any added efficiency that would greatly impact the performance of the java application using the "double[]" array? Or would the difference only be negligible?

Comment: Repeat after me: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Do what makes sense.

Comment: you can also try `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: Scalability? We don't need no stinkin' scalability!

Comment: How about `new DataStore(4, 3, 2, 1, 0);` so you can use the natural gravitational force of decreasing numbers

Comment: Do the 5 values represent the *same*, so you'd want to loop through and handle them the same? If so, option 1 is right, and option 2 is wrong, since you cannot loop through them (without using slow reflection). Are the 5 values *different*, so naming them individually makes the code more readable/understandable? Then option 1 is wrong and option 2 is right. As you can see, the choice is not about performance, it's about your *code*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, primitive scalar types like `double[]` will be faster for most uses. Much faster, in many cases. However, it is *highly* unlikely that you'll notice any kind of difference in most applications.

Someone else did a relevant benchmark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25244805/145279).

But, always remember:

[image: Premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming!]