# Java Json to List of Lists

Tags: java, json, gson

There is a List of Lists of Float values as Json, how is it possible to get `List<List<Float>>`?

I tried something like:

```
class MyLine{
  List<Float> values;
}
String firstData = "[[0.11492168, -0.30645782, 9.835381], [0.12449849, -0.29688102, 9.844957]]"
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<MyLine> firstList = gson.fromJson(firstData, new TypeToken<List<MyLine>>(){}.getType());
```

but I have an error `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: use gson  did you?

Comment: is that a valid JSON in your string??

Comment: @jackjay yes it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to define your own wrapper class, you can just directly use a type token of `List<List<Float>>` like so:

```
String firstData = "[[0.11492168, -0.30645782, 9.835381], [0.12449849, -0.29688102, 9.844957]]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<List<Float>> firstList = gson.fromJson(firstData, new TypeToken<List<List<Float>>>() {}.getType());

System.out.println(firstList);
// prints [[0.11492168, -0.30645782, 9.835381], [0.12449849, -0.29688102, 9.844957]]
```

A `List<MyLine>` isn't actually a `List<List<Float>>` unless `MyLine` itself is a `List`.  Rather, it's a `List` of a class that *contains* a `List<Float>`.

Answer (score 0):

azurefrog's answer is perfect for your question. You might also consider switching to another target deserialization type. The rationale: `List<List<Float>>` is actually a list of lists of float wrappers where every wrapper holds a float value in your JVM heap separated, whilst `float[][]` is an array of arrays of primitive floats where each float value does not require a wrapper box for a single float value in the heap (you can consider an array of primitives a sequence of values with plain memory layout) thus saving memory from more "aggressive" consumption. Here is a [good Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199359/why-do-people-still-use-primitive-types-in-java) describing the differences between the objects and primitives. Sure, you won't see a significant difference for tiny arrays, but in case you would like to try it out, you don't even need a type token (because arrays, unlike generics, allow `.class` notation):

```java
final float[][] values = gson.fromJson(firstData, float[][].class);
...
```