# Java comparison speed

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I was wondering how big is speed difference in object vs. primitive comparison. Imagine this piece of code from linked list implementation, which method is "better" to use?

```
int size = 0;
Node head;

boolean isEmpty1() {
   return head == null;
}

boolean isEmpty2() {
   return size == 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the one you want. It won't make any difference.

Comment: It's more efficient to use primitives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5199425/2115684 - You can check this yourself in a unit test. For your example however, because of the simple `==` check rather than a `.equals()`, it shouldn't be much different.

Comment: @JonathanSterling this is not quite the same as the given problem. Look at [Stephen C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44196063/4216641) for some details.

Comment: @JonathanSterling this is a totally unrelated issue. OP compares object references here.

Comment: @JonathanSterling - That is comparing `int == int` versus `Integer == int`.  The second case has the overhead of unboxing.

Comment: I edited my comment within seconds, but still got caught out :-p. In general terms, it's better to use primitives where possible. However, in this example, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Again ... the "use primitives" advice applies *only* to boxed versus unboxed types.  For other cases, you need to analyse the specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparison of `int` values and comparison of reference values using `==` should take the same time on a modern 32bit or 64bit machine.

---

I should also point out that premature micro-optimization is *typically* a bad idea.  Unless you are an extraordinary programmer, your intuition on what is faster and what *needs* to be optimized will be less than perfect.  The chances are that if you optimize based on your intuition (or our intuition!) you will waste a lot of time with little measurable benefit.